# How to get the identity of an inserted row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the `IDENTITY` of an inserted row?

I know about `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but don't understand the implications or impacts attached to each. How do these differ, and when would each be used?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Table1(fields...) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (...)`, or older method: `INSERT INTO Table1(fields...) VALUES (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` you can get it in c# using ExecuteScalar().

Answer (score 1717, accepted):

- [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.  **You need to be careful here**, since it's across scopes.  You could get a value from a trigger, instead of your current statement.
- [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.  **Generally what you want to use**.
- [`IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.  This lets you specify which table you want the value from, in case the two above aren't quite what you need (**very rare**).  Also, as @[Guy Starbuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row#42665) mentioned, "You could use this if you want to get the current IDENTITY value for a table that you have not inserted a record into."
- The [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) of the `INSERT` statement will let you access every row that was inserted via that statement.  Since it's scoped to the specific statement, it's **more straightforward** than the other functions above.  However, it's a little **more verbose** (you'll need to insert into a table variable/temp table and then query that) and it gives results even in an error scenario where the statement is rolled back.  That said, if your query uses a parallel execution plan, this is the **only guaranteed method** for getting the identity (short of turning off parallelism). However, it is executed *before* triggers and cannot be used to return trigger-generated values.

Comment: known bug with SCOPE_IDENTITY() returning the wrong values: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/ the work around is to not run the INSERT in a Multi Processor Parallel Plan or use the OUTPUT clause

Comment: ident_current is extremely dangerous to data integrity. We had someone use that and simluatanous actions onthe database resulted on the child tables getting assigned to the wrong person. Almost imopossible to fix the data when that happens.

Comment: Almost every time I have ever wanted 'identity', I have wanted to know the key(s) of the record(s) I just inserted.  If that is your situation, you want to use the OUTPUT clause.  If you want something else, apply the effort to read and understand bdukes response.

Comment: For another reason not to use @@Indentity is that in my experience it is O(n) and SCOPE_IDENTITY() is O(1).  It only showed up on a really big table.

Comment: With `output` you don't need to create a temp table to store and query the results.  Just leave off the `into` part of the output clause and it will output them to a resultset.

Comment: To save others from panicing, the bug mentioned above was fixed in  Cumulative Update 5 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1.

Comment: Why doesn't SCOPE_IDENTITY's limiting to the current scope make it safe to use?

Comment: Can we get identity from multiple insert?

Comment: Note that it seems you can't use OUTPUT when the two tables have an fkey relationship, unless you use an intermediary temp table (which has to be already defined before the INSERT statement).

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause is also buggy in that it doesn't takes into account the execution of triggers and also has problems with timestamps. I had to change the return of values from `OUTPUT` back to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in an extra `SELECT` precisely for this bug. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198916/2557263

Comment: @niico, I think the recommendation is the same as it has been, which is that `OUTPUT` is the "best" so long as you aren't using triggers and are handling errors, but `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is the simplest and very rarely has issues

Comment: Pracmatically: Generate a uuid and insert it. Then you can easily identify your row.

Comment: Note also that the big advantage of OUTPUT over the other methods is that *it can capture* ***multiple*** *generated identity values* when you insert multiple rows.

Answer (score 226):

I believe the safest and most accurate method of retrieving the inserted id would be  using the output clause.

for example (taken from the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) article)

> ```
> USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
> GO
> DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
>                            Name varchar(50),
>                            ModifiedDate datetime);
> INSERT Production.ScrapReason
>     OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
>         INTO @MyTableVar
> VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());
>
> --Display the result set of the table variable.
> SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;
> --Display the result set of the table.
> SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate 
> FROM Production.ScrapReason;
> GO
> ```

Comment: Yes this is the correct method going forward, only use one of the others if you are not on SQL Server 2008 (we skipped 2005 so not sure if OUTPUT was available then)

Comment: @HLGEM There's an [MSDN page for `OUTPUT` in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), so looks like it's just SQL Server 2000 and earlier that are without it

Comment: For a really concise example to just get the inserted ID, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10999467/2003325

Comment: Your use of INTO with OUTPUT is a good idea.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/07/11/update-with-output-clause-triggers-and-sqlmoreresults/  (From a comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Comment: I Just learned about this OUTPUT INSERT feature, that looks like the real answer, works very well in sqlserver, but doesn't work with SqlClient class, it throws System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot find either column "INSERTED" or the user-defined function or aggregate "INSERTED.Id", or the name is ambiguous.', I'm raising a question in other thread so if anybody knows the solution, will be appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786640/how-can-i-get-inserted-id-in-sql-server-while-using-sqlclient-class

Comment: Is it possible to get columns from the VALUES part (or SELECT if you use that)? The examples in MSDN shows that on the DELETE statement, but I cannot get it to work on SELECT/VALUES

Answer (score 134):

I'm saying the same thing as the other guys, so everyone's correct, I'm just trying to make it more clear.

`@@IDENTITY` returns the id of the last thing that was inserted by your client's connection to the database.
Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes a trigger will go and insert a new row that you don't know about, and you'll get the ID from this new row, instead of the one you want

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` solves this problem. It returns the id of the last thing that *you inserted* in the SQL code *you sent* to the database. If triggers go and create extra rows, they won't cause the wrong value to get returned. Hooray

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last ID that was inserted by anyone. If some other app happens to insert another row at an unforunate time, you'll get the ID of that row instead of your one.

If you want to play it safe, always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. If you stick with `@@IDENTITY` and someone decides to add a trigger later on, all your code will break.

Comment: What if let's say 2 or 5 users will crate a record at the same time, will 
SCOPE_IDENTITY() gave us that right record for each user, or?

Comment: @SlavaCa it returns the right record for each SQL statement, per connection.

If you have 5 users creating records at the same time, it is likely that will be 5 different database connections, so each would get their own identity. It works :-)

Answer (score 77):

The best (read: safest) way to get the identity of a newly-inserted row is by using the `output` clause:

```
create table TableWithIdentity
           ( IdentityColumnName int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
             ... )

-- type of this table's column must match the type of the
-- identity column of the table you'll be inserting into
declare @IdentityOutput table ( ID int )

insert TableWithIdentity
     ( ... )
output inserted.IdentityColumnName into @IdentityOutput
values
     ( ... )

select @IdentityValue = (select ID from @IdentityOutput)
```

Comment: SQL server clustering is a high availability feature and has no bearing on parallelism. It is very uncommon for single row inserts (the most common case for `scope_identity()`) to get parallel plans anyway. And this bug was fixed more than a year before this answer.

Comment: What do you mean by parallelism.

Comment: @MartinSmith The client wasn't willing to allow downtime on their server cluster to install the CU fixing this issue (not joking), so the only solution was for us to rewrite all the SQL to use `output` instead of `scope_identity()`. I have removed the FUD about clustering in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only example I've been able to find that shows how to use the value from the output in a variable instead of just outputting it.

Answer (score 38):

Add

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
```

to the end of your insert sql statement, then

```
NewId = command.ExecuteScalar()
```

will retrieve it.

Comment: Where are you getting `NewId` from? And what is its declared type? To store `command.ExecuteScalar()` in it I am assuming it is an `Object`?

Comment: @TylerH In this example, the first part is SQL (the select) and the second part is .NET (the ExecuteScaler), so NewId assumed to be variable that the SQL returns to C#.

Comment: @b.pell I'm aware the second part is C# and not SQL; I'm asking OP to explain what each part means since they created that part out of thin air, and didn't show how to use it as part of the presumed solution.

Comment: Thank you for this. `$"INSERT INTO PageCacher_Cycles (CycleStart) VALUES ('{DateTime.Now}'); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";` worked for me

Answer (score 26):

From MSDN

> @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, and IDENT_CURRENT are similar functions in that they return the last value inserted into the IDENTITY column of a table.
>
> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.
>
> IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope. For more information, see IDENT_CURRENT.

- IDENT_CURRENT is a function which takes a table as a argument.
- @@IDENTITY may return confusing result when you have an trigger on the table
- SCOPE_IDENTITY is your hero most of the time.

Answer (score 25):

When you use Entity Framework, it internally uses the `OUTPUT` technique to return the newly inserted ID value

```
DECLARE @generated_keys table([Id] uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO TurboEncabulators(StatorSlots)
OUTPUT inserted.TurboEncabulatorID INTO @generated_keys
VALUES('Malleable logarithmic casing');

SELECT t.[TurboEncabulatorID ]
FROM @generated_keys AS g 
   JOIN dbo.TurboEncabulators AS t 
   ON g.Id = t.TurboEncabulatorID 
   WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

The output results are stored in a temporary table variable, joined back to the table, and return the row value out of the table.

Note: I have no idea why EF would inner join the ephemeral table back to the real table (under what circumstances would the two not match).

But that's what EF does.

This technique (`OUTPUT`) is only available on SQL Server 2008 or newer.

### **Edit** - The reason for the join

The reason that Entity Framework joins back to the original table, rather than simply use the `OUTPUT` values is because EF also uses this technique to get the `rowversion` of a newly inserted row.

You can use optimistic concurrency in your entity framework models by [using the `Timestamp` attribute:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
public class TurboEncabulator
{
   public String StatorSlots;

   [Timestamp]
   public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

When you do this, Entity Framework will need the `rowversion` of the newly inserted row:

```
DECLARE @generated_keys table([Id] uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO TurboEncabulators(StatorSlots)
OUTPUT inserted.TurboEncabulatorID INTO @generated_keys
VALUES('Malleable logarithmic casing');

SELECT t.[TurboEncabulatorID], t.[RowVersion]
FROM @generated_keys AS g 
   JOIN dbo.TurboEncabulators AS t 
   ON g.Id = t.TurboEncabulatorID 
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

And in order to retrieve this `Timestamp` you **cannot** use an `OUTPUT` clause.

That's because if there's a trigger on the table, any `Timestamp` you OUTPUT will be wrong:

| Action | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| Initial insert | 1 |
| OUTPUT clause outputs: | 1 |
| Trigger modifies row | 2 |

The returned timestamp will **never** be correct if you have a trigger on the table. So you **must** use a separate `SELECT`.

### Second reason you must use the join

And even if you were willing to suffer the incorrect rowversion, the other reason to perform a separate `SELECT` is that you cannot OUTPUT a `rowversion` into a table variable:

```
DECLARE @generated_keys table([Id] uniqueidentifier, [Rowversion] timestamp)

INSERT INTO TurboEncabulators(StatorSlots)
OUTPUT inserted.TurboEncabulatorID, inserted.Rowversion INTO @generated_keys
VALUES('Malleable logarithmic casing');
```

### Third reason you must use the join

The third reason to do it is for symmetry. When performing an `UPDATE` on a table with a trigger, you **cannot** use an `OUTPUT` clause. Trying do `UPDATE` with an `OUTPUT` is not supported, and will give an error:

- [Cannot use UPDATE with OUTPUT clause when a trigger is on the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table)

The only way to do it is with a follow-up `SELECT` statement:

```
UPDATE TurboEncabulators
SET StatorSlots = 'Lotus-O deltoid type'
WHERE ((TurboEncabulatorID = 1) AND (RowVersion = 792))

SELECT RowVersion
FROM TurboEncabulators
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND TurboEncabulatorID = 1
```

### Entity Framework 7 and the Intentional Won't-Fix Crash

Entity Framework 7 [introduced a breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers) that causes EF to:

- crash if the table has a trigger
- return the wrong rowversion

It's the terrible, wrong-headed, premature optimization, that breaks all existing code over a [non-issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27372).

- They're throwing developers into the pit of failure
- rather than throwing them into [the pit of success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/)

Everyone's code now contains a unexploded landmine; just waiting for you to accidentally step on it—making it one more thing you have to be sure to go out of your way to turn off in every class, in every project, from nowm until the heat death of the universe. I wish they would stop doing the wrong thing.

Comment: i imagine they match them to ensure integrity (e.g. in optimistic concurrency mode, while you are selecting from the table variable, someone may have removed the inserter rows).

Also, love your `TurboEncabulators` :)

Answer (score 23):

I can't speak to other versions of SQL Server, but in 2012, outputting directly works just fine.  You don't need to bother with a temporary table.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES (...)
```

By the way, this technique also works when inserting multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES
    (...),
    (...),
    (...)
```

Output

```
ID
2
3
4
```

Comment: If you want to use it later though, I imagine you need the temp table

Comment: @JohnOsborne You are welcome to use a temp table if you like, but my point was that it's not a requirement of `OUTPUT`.  If you don't need the temp table, then your query ends up being much simpler.

Answer (score 17):

**@@IDENTITY** is the last identity inserted using the current SQL Connection.  This is a good value to return from an insert stored procedure, where you just need the identity inserted for your new record, and don't care if more rows were added afterward.

**SCOPE_IDENTITY** is the last identity inserted using the current SQL Connection, and in the current scope -- that is, if there was a second IDENTITY inserted based on a trigger after your insert, it would not be reflected in SCOPE_IDENTITY, only the insert you performed. Frankly, I have never had a reason to use this.

**IDENT_CURRENT(tablename)** is the last identity inserted regardless of connection or scope.  You could use this if you want to get the current IDENTITY value for a table that you have not inserted a record into.

Comment: You should never use @@identity for this purpose. If someone adds a trigger later, you will lose data integrity. @@identiy is an extremely dangerous practice.

Comment: "value for a table that you have <<not>> inserted a record into." Really?

Answer (score 15):

**ALWAYS** use scope_identity(), there's NEVER a need for anything else.

Comment: Not quite *never* but 99 times out of 100, you'll use Scope_Identity().

Comment: For what have you ever used anything else?

Comment: if you insert several rows with an INSERT-SELECT, you would need to capture the multiple IDs using the OUTPUT clause

Comment: @KM: Yes, but I referred to scope_identity vs @@identity vs ident_current. OUTPUT is a completely different class and often useful.

Comment: Check out Orry's ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073578/2440976)  answer to this question - in parallelism, and just as a best practice, you would be wise to follow his setup... just brilliant!

Comment: Why is it better than Output Inserted.Id?

Answer (score 3):

One other way to guarantee the identity of the rows you insert is to specify the identity values and use the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and then `OFF`. This guarantees you know exactly what the identity values are! As long as the values are not in use then you can insert these values into the identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE #foo 
  ( 
     fooid   INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
     fooname VARCHAR(20) 
  ) 

SELECT @@Identity            AS [@@Identity], 
       Scope_identity()      AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY()], 
       Ident_current('#Foo') AS [IDENT_CURRENT] 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #foo ON 

INSERT INTO #foo 
            (fooid, 
             fooname) 
VALUES      (1, 
             'one'), 
            (2, 
             'Two') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #foo OFF 

SELECT @@Identity            AS [@@Identity], 
       Scope_identity()      AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY()], 
       Ident_current('#Foo') AS [IDENT_CURRENT] 

INSERT INTO #foo 
            (fooname) 
VALUES      ('Three') 

SELECT @@Identity            AS [@@Identity], 
       Scope_identity()      AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY()], 
       Ident_current('#Foo') AS [IDENT_CURRENT] 

-- YOU CAN INSERT  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #foo ON 

INSERT INTO #foo 
            (fooid, 
             fooname) 
VALUES      (10, 
             'Ten'), 
            (11, 
             'Eleven') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #foo OFF 

SELECT @@Identity            AS [@@Identity], 
       Scope_identity()      AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY()], 
       Ident_current('#Foo') AS [IDENT_CURRENT] 

SELECT * 
FROM   #foo
```

This can be a very useful technique if you are loading data from another source or merging data from two databases etc.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `uuid` and also insert it to a column. Then you can easily identify your row with the uuid. Thats the only 100% working solution you can implement. All the other solutions are too complicated or are not working in same edge cases.
E.g.:

**1) Create row**

```
INSERT INTO table (uuid, name, street, zip) 
        VALUES ('2f802845-447b-4caa-8783-2086a0a8d437', 'Peter', 'Mainstreet 7', '88888');
```

**2) Get created row**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid='2f802845-447b-4caa-8783-2086a0a8d437';
```

Comment: Don't forget to create a index for the `uuid` in the database. So the row will be found faster.

Comment: For node.js you can use this module to simply create a uuid: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid`. 
`const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4'); const uuid = uuidv4()`

Comment: A GUID is not an identity value, it has some backdraws compared to a simple integer.

Comment: Also if the UUID is generated at the SQL table level as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` datatype with a default of `newid()` then you will not be able to get it using this method.  So you would need to INSERT, leaving the UUID blank and then do the OUTPUT INSERTED.uuid in order to get it

Comment: FYI - inserts are designed to operate most efficiently when using sequential identity numbers (Specifically the indexes).

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an older thread, there is a newer way to do this which avoids some of the pitfalls of the IDENTITY column in older versions of SQL Server, [like gaps in the identity values after server reboots](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88930/identity-value-jumps-when-restarting-sql-server). Sequences are available in SQL Server 2016 and forward which is the newer way is to create a SEQUENCE object using TSQL.  This allows you create your own numeric sequence object in SQL Server and control how it increments.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy1  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

Then in TSQL you would do the following to get the next sequence ID:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR CountBy1 AS SequenceID
GO
```

Here are the links to [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) and [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: Sequences have the very same problems of identity, like the gaps (which aren't really problems).

Comment: The identity gaps occurred randomly when the SQL Server was restarted.  These gaps do not occur in the new SEQUENCE increments, unless the developer does not use the SEQUENCE that is generated, or rolls back a transaction that was to use the next SEQUENCE id.   From the online documentation: The sequence object generates numbers according to its definition, but the sequence object does not control how the numbers are used. Sequence numbers inserted into a table can have gaps when a transaction is rolled back, ... or when sequence numbers are allocated without using them in tables.

Answer (score -1):

Complete solution in SQL and ADO.NET

```
 const string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table1] (...) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id VALUES (...)";

using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = sql;
 var outputIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        command.Parameters.Add(outputIdParameter);

        await connection.OpenAsync();

        var outputId= await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

        await connection.CloseAsync();
        
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(outputId);
```

Answer (score -3):

After Your Insert Statement you need to add this. And Make sure about the table name where data is inserting.You will get current row no where row affected just now by your insert statement.

```
IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')
```

Comment: Did you notice this exact same suggestion has been answered several times before?

Comment: yes. but i am trying to describe the solution in my own way.

Comment: And if someone else have inserted a row in between your insert statement and your IDENT_CURRENT() call, you'll get the id of the record someone else have inserted - probably not what you want.
As noted in most of the replies above - in most cases you should rather use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: @Trondster very well put. I would say either that or `set transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE`  or again `WITH(HOLDLOCK)`