# @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT [sql server 2005]

Tags: sql-server-2005, identity-column

Which should i use to get last inserted record id in sql server 2005?

I searched stackoverflow and i found this,

[SQL: How to get the id of values I just INSERTed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651/sql-how-to-get-the-id-of-values-i-just-inserted)

**Comment of the best answer:**

there are known bugs with SCOPE_IDENTITY() in sql server 2005, not sure about 2008, the OUTPUT clause can return a set of IDs if necessary...

```
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id from Table
```

I am uisng sql server 2005... Any suggestion

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: @Oded I ve asked this question based on the comment...

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question directly about this, like `What are the bugs, and what can be done about them...`

Comment: #1 google result for **scope_identity bug** http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what these "knows bugs" in SCOPE_IDENTITY() should be. The only thing I'm currently aware of is here: [Six reasons you should be nervous about parallelism](https://sqlblog.org/2009/03/21/six-reasons-you-should-be-nervous-about-parallelism) mentioned as the very first point.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Comment: Ah, okay. Same one as in my link. :-)

Comment: fyi, that link is the #6 google result for **scope_dientity bug**

Answer (score 4):

### Triggers

Using `@@identity` is reliant on the fact that there are no triggers in your database creating records elsewhere.

If you create a record but a trigger then creates a log entry for the creation, `@@identity` will return you the id of the log entry in the log table.