# Are table variables thread safe on sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For example, I am going to use the following table variable inside one of my stored procedures;

```
DECLARE @MyTempTable TABLE 
(
   someField int,
   someFieldMore nvarchar(50)
)
```

Is this variable thread safe? if multiple request comes at the same time, do you think there would be a conflict?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

"Thread safe" would be "scope-safe" or "connection-safe" in SQL Server. Scope-safe implies connection-safe too.

Table variables are like normal variables: local to that scope. Each connection is isolated from each other, and each connection is a series of scopes

The best example of this is the difference between

- SCOPE_IDENTITY = scope safe
- @@IDENTITY = connection safe, not scope safe
- IDENT_CURRENT = not safe either way

See: [@@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT [sql server 2005]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154109/identity-vs-scope-identity-vs-ident-current-sql-server-2005)

Comment: thanks for the answer @gbn. just another thing comes to my mind after your answer : is CURSOR scope safe? for example if I use this cursor in one of my sp, what would happen if multiple requests comes at the same time? : `DECLARE cr_cursor CURSOR FOR ...` I will also open and close the cursor inside the sp and at the end, I will use `DEALLOCATE cr_cursor`

Comment: @tugberk: that's probably worth another question. I haven't used a cursor in years and other folk will know better than me.

Answer (score 3):

The table variable is local in the scope where it is created. Two simultanious connections does not share the table variable.