# Calling identity while creating a new row

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm trying to assign integer to a newly created row:

```
INSERT INTO wcategory (name, description) values ('Manager','Hotel Managment');
INSERT INTO worker (name, categoryID) values ('User', CAL IDENTITY() );
```

However I seem to be getting unexpected token CALL error.
Any idea how to call last identity correctly? or at least is there a work aroud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @@identity or scope_identity(). Save it in a variable and then use it in the next insert statement.

Comment: removing CALL from CAL IDENTITY worked as well. Thanks for the answer though, it works as well.

Comment: The two are not identical. ["SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2154129/104223