# Equivalent of mysql_insert_id() for ms sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: How to get the id of values I just INSERTed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651/sql-how-to-get-the-id-of-values-i-just-inserted)

For PHP, What's equivalent of `mysql_insert_id()` for sql server 2012?

`sqlsrv_insert_id()` does not seem to exist.

Say this is the code

```
  if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

for mysql,
how should I do it for sql server?

Comment: Hmm..but it doesn't provide a php syntax?

Comment: PDO has [lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), might be a good idea to switch to PDO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php
Over there at the comments you have the php syntax at the comments:

```
function mssql_insert_id() { 
    $id = 0; 
    $res = mssql_query("SELECT @@identity AS id"); 
    if ($row = mssql_fetch_array($res, MSSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        $id = $row["id"]; 
    } 
    return $id; 
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)..use mysql for sqlsrv?

Comment: No, that makes little sense, i copied and pasted from the link i referenced, I think they had a typo there, I will fix what I copy-pasted, please let us know if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Or query it:

```
SELECT `column_id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `column_id` DESC TOP 1
```

TOP is the MySql equivalent of LIMIT