# Sql Server return the value of identity column after insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible in sql server using stored procedure to return the identity column value in a table against which some values are inserted? For example using stored procedure if we insert data in a table:

Table TBL

- UserID integer, identity, auto-incremented
- Name varchar
- UserName varchar
- Password varchar

So if I run the store procedure inserting some values like:

```
 Insert into TBL (Name, UserName, Password)
 Values ('example', 'example', '$2a$12$00WFrz3dOfLaIgpTYRJ9CeuB6VicjLGhLset8WtFrzvtpRekcP1lq')
```

How can I return the value of `UserID` at which this insertion will take place. I need The value of UserID for some other operations, can anybody solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
Insert into TBL (Name, UserName, Password) Output Inserted.IdentityColumnName
 Values ('example', 'example', 'example')
```

Comment: @AmitSingh What is the difference between this and scope_identity? The sentence `Inserted.IdentityColumnName` always will return a correct identity?, What will happen if insert at the same time from two inserts?.

Comment: @GastonF. it will always give the right value it give output of any colunmn not only identity means it can return whole row which is inserted..u can try by typnig inserted.anycolumnname

Comment: @AmitSingh: great! +1, your post i helped me for find the differences in the use between this and `scope_identity()`, and I found something very crazy, the `scope_identity()` have a bug at least until version 2008, i do not know after that, anyway from Microsoft suggested use `Output Inserted...`...wow!. Check this [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value). Thanks.

Comment: Note that the OUTPUT statement will return more than 1 row if your INSERT inserted more than 1 row, with a row containing each identity inserted, whereas SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the last identity value inserted. So if you use SCOPE_IDENTITY() you better be sure that you can only ever insert 1 row. This is the case in your example.

Comment: Is it possible to store the ID in a variable when using `OUTPUT`?

Answer (score 14):

send an output parameter like

```
@newId int output
```

at the end use

```
    select @newId = Scope_Identity() 

     return @newId
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

after the insert statement

Please refer the following links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly get back Identity columns using SqlServer's OUTPUT clause: 
Assuming you have an identity/auto-increment column called ID:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO [xyz].[myTable] (Field1, Field2, Field3) OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES  (1, 2, '3')';
```

Note that in Perl DBI you would then execute the INSERT statement, just like it was a SELECT.
And capture the output like it was a SELECT

```
$sth->execute($sql);
@row=$sth->fetchrow_array; #Only 1 val in 1 row returned
print "Inserted ID: ", $row[0], "\n";
```

Presumably this is preferable because it doesn't require another request.

Comment: How is this any different than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

Here goes a bunch of different ways to get the ID, including Scope_Identity:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655/1504882

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scope_Identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to get the last value.

Have a read of these too:

- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record
- [Stored procedure - return identity as output parameter or scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142444/stored-procedure-return-identity-as-output-parameter-or-scalar)

Comment: @user2599269, I added a couple.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SELECT @@IDENTITY as well

Comment: Please do not use that, as @@IDENTITY returns the last identity value use for ALL scopes, not just the current one, which can be wrong.