# INSERT statement for One to Many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

So I'm working on a project to catalog my games and I've run into an issue. I have a DB with two tables that breakdown as follows:

**Game_Information**

- gameId(PK)  Is Identity(auto-increments)
- gamePrice
- name
- edition

**Game_Notes**

- noteId(PK)  Is Identity(auto-increments)
- notes
- noteDate
- gameId(FK)

One game can have many notes, so there's a one to many relation between the two tables where a column within "Game_Notes" called  "gameId" is a FK/references the primary key of "Game_Information" by the same name.

Now within Webmatrix, I've coded a page that lets me enter a game's price, name, and edition. Within that same page I can also add a note about the game. On post, page takes information from textboxes and tries to execute the following:

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO Game_Information (gamePrice, name, edition) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", gamePrice, name, edition); 
db.Execute("INSERT INTO Game_Notes(notes, noteDate) VALUES (@0, @1)", notes, noteDate);
```

Now this works and puts the information in the correct tables but it leaves gameId(FK) within "Game_Notes" empty.

What I would like is that the number assigned to gameId(PK) in "Game_Information" reflects in gameId(FK) in "Game_Notes".

Anyone can help me on this or point to articles I can read? Thanks.

-Update-
Made question clearer.

Comment: GameID should be an identity in `Game_Information`, but a Foreign Key in `Game_Notes`.

Comment: First of all you should make Store procedure and second use scope_identity() to insert gameid in GameNotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you're trying to accomplish two things:

1. Get the gameId of the newly inserted record in Game_Information
2. Use that gameId in the following insert statement to Game_Notes

While there are countless ways to do this, using an "output" value would be one suggestion. Something like:

```
var id = db.QueryValue("INSERT INTO Game_Information (gamePrice, name, edition) output Inserted.gameId VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", gamePrice, name, edition);
```

Check out some posts for more information on this: [Sql Server return the value of identity column after insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993606/sql-server-return-the-value-of-identity-column-after-insert-statement)

Then, use that id in the following statement:

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO Game_Notes(gameId, notes, noteDate) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", id, notes, noteDate);
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of this, just trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help Phas1c. Tried your code though it's only adding "1" to all entries into "Game_Notes", it's a good start along with the reading.

Comment: Changing db.Execute to db.QueryValue resolves the issue with the "1".

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `gameId` in your second db.execute statement

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO Game_Notes(gameId, notes, noteDate) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", gameId, notes, noteDate);
```

Comment: An error on my part tshoemake. Meant to type "gamePrice" instead of "gameId". gameId is an identity. Man brain is fried today.

Comment: You should edit your question, I no longer follow what you're wanting.

Comment: Updated question to make it clear. Apologize for the confusion.