# How do I execute sql text passed as an sp parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure with an nvarchar parameter. I expect callers to supply the text for a sql command when using this SP.

How do I execute the supplied sql command from within the SP?

Is this even possible?-

I thought it was possible using EXEC but the following:

```
EXEC @script
```

errors indicating it can't find a stored procedure by the given name. Since it's a script this is obviously accurate, but leads me to think it's not working as expected.

Comment: I agree with all the security comments, but you can try

[   EXEC (@script)    ]

which should work.

Comment: @Sparky: While valid, `EXEC` won't cache the query plan while `EXEC sp_executesql` will: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: True, but if the users are going to supply text for SQL (which scares me, but), I would expect the query plans to vary.    Now, if we can only convince people NOT to let users do this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @nvarchar_parameter

END
```

...assuming the parameter is an entire SQL query.  If not:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ...' + @nvarchar_parameter

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Be aware of [SQL Injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), and I highly recommend reading [The curse and blessing of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: sp_executesql made the difference. Looks like the article will explain why. Thanks.

Comment: @TheDeeno sp_executesql is **not** enough. It will still allow UPDATE, CREATE, and DROP statements to go through.  You need to limit it to a user that only has dbreader

Comment: What's the reason for wrapping the EXEC sp_executesql call in a BEGIN/END block?

Answer (score 0):

you can just exec @sqlStatement from within your sp.  Though, its not the best thing to do because it opens you up to sql injection.  You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731821/t-sql-exec-and-scope)

Comment: While valid, `EXEC` won't cache the query plan while `EXEC sp_executesql` will: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Ah, I edited to slow. I'm fine with injection risk since this will be used by admins only. I must be doing something wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You use `EXECUTE` passing it the command as a string.  Note this could open your system up to serious vulnerabilities given that it is difficult to verify the non-maliciousness of the SQL statements you are blindly executing.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I execute the supplied sql command from within the SP?

Very carefully. That code could do anything, including add or delete records, or even whole tables or databases.

To be safe about this, you need to create a separate user account that only has dbreader permissions on just a small set of allowed tables/views and use the [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) command to limit the context to that user.