# How can I get the GUID value of a new row after inserting it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the Id of newly inserted record in Sqlserver. I have checked the `Scope_Identity()` but this is said to return the value of the autoincrement column. The column I am using for Id is Guid. I want this Guid column value after the insert. How should this be achieved? Or I must have to write a custom tedious function to get the Id of newly inserted record.

Comment: I don't understand your issue.  Where is the guid being created?  Whether it is in your client code, or in a stored procedure in the database, simply use the value at the point where you create it.

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/sql-server-scope-identity-for-guids

Comment: OUTPUT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: hhh.... This is called coding fever... Thanks buddy.. I am laughing at myself..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try and use [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (<Column1>, <Column2>, <Column3>) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES (<Value1>, <Value2>, <Value3>)
```

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/t-sql-identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last), has a lot more info on the different types of identity selection, you should check it out.

**EDIT**

You would use this as a regular scalar:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("...");
Guid id = (Guid) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: And how would you read this value returned in `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` in C#?

Comment: @Paul You would use it in the same way as a scalar (it returns a single value). Check my Edit.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know `ExecuteScalar` could return anything other than an `int`. So you're saying you could do something like `Guid id = (Guid) command.ExecuteScalar();`, since the question is specifically asking how to return a `guid`.

Comment: @Paul Yeah absolutely, `ExecuteScalar` simply returns the first column from the first row from the result set, i.e. - a single value, it could be anything. Also thanks for the catch, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Could we use  `command.ExecuteReader()` if we wanted to get back a list of GUIDs for *all the inserted rows* (i.e. if we insert multiple rows?) ([`ExecuteScalar` vs `ExecuteReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974203/1175496))