# Get Identity Column Value in C# 'Dataset'--Access DataBase

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, dataset

I want to retrieve identity column value after running Insert or Update (using Access DB in C#). How can I do it?

i use a Typed dataset to fill and update...

Comment: We're going to need much better details of what you're trying to accomplish and how before we can help.

Comment: please elaborate your question. IMHO is any link between partial class and id obtaining.

Comment: finally, the question should be like **"I want to retrieve identity column value after running Insert or Update (using Access DB in C#). How can I do it?"**

Comment: I think you are trying to ask to Question. 1. How to implement partial class in C#. 2. How to implement insertion, deletion and updation in MS-Access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For retrieving the identity of inserted rows see this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28VS.80%29.aspx

This link describes how to find the value of an inserted row in SQL, you then need to return that row in a SELECT statement (as Access does not support return parameters)

You may also be interested in this question, which compares the different methods of returning the identity.

[Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Answer (score 1):

Ms-Access C# connectivity  for insertion deletion updation for identity column

[Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: plz attention to my question.

i want get identity code in access database after information save

Comment: @hosseinsinohe: plz post your questions to be clear ones for everybody. First of all think WHAT exactly you want and then edit a question...

Comment: @hosseinsinohe should i consider that you dont want to implement partial class at this point ?

Comment: I want get Auto-Increment Column Value after insert or update database.

 i use 'Typed Dataset' And 'Access DataBase'.
I can not write En very well
plz help me

Comment: @hosseinsinohe sry then i dont know about typed dataset. U need to modify your question then, along with title. Modify your question with this comment that u wrote now

Answer (score 1):

(sorry I cannot post a comment)
It sounds to me like he is using an ADO.net DataSet, and wants to retrieve an the value of an auto-increment column after inserting a value.
I don't know where you are all getting partial classes from, he's saying he can't figure out how to do it in C#, not that he doesn't want it in C#.

Comment: @BlueRaja Now the title has been edited by him. B4 that title had implementing partial class also

Answer (score 0):

In Find answer of My Question

the Flowing Links Helped me to write a partial Class to Validate Rows in Dataset And Write a Code to Recive a AutoIncrement Column Value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171896(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f7ey06d(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1120xds5(VS.80).aspx

thank you