# How do I get the primary key of the row I just inserted into a typed dataset in .net?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have some VB.net code that inserts data into my SQL database using a typed dataset as follows:

> dim usersTa As New authorizedUsersTableAdapters.Authorized_UsersTableAdapter
>   usersTa.Connection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
>   usersTa.Insert(first_name, last_name)

In the database, there is a primary key by which I identify the rows.  What is the most efficient way to find out the primary key of the row that I just inserted when I run this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are executing some kind of SQL in the `Authorized_UsersTableAdapter.Insert()` method.

In order to return the identifier you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Example if your identifier is an Int.

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = ...
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(INSERT INTO T (Name) VALUES('Test')" & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) & "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As TheId", conn)
Dim tId As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
```

Comment: The code that is running to actually insert the data is generated by the designer when I add the typed dataset objects to my project.

I've been directed to avoid having SQL statements in my code.

Comment: I hate to tell you, but the designer is writing SQL statements to be executed in your code. If you don't have a problem with that, then you shouldn't have any problem modifying the SQL that the designer generated for you. Either way, some SQL somewhere has to get executed.

Comment: Then I would follow @Oded answer and wrap SCOPE_IDENTITY in a StoredProc. If you don't want to do this you have to require the recently inserted row which is inefficient. In some cases auto generation removes flexibility.

Comment: @Jermeny, I couldn't agree more. I don't like autogenerated code which is "hidden" somewhere. I'd rather pack the SQL in a business layer somewhere.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was very informative.  One of my co-workers has been encouraging me to use the LINQ queries and these typed dataset seem to help facilitate that.

Comment: [Here's](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/10/31/returning-the-identity-column-value-from-a-tableadapter-dbdirect-method/) an MS blog entry that suggests adding, in the query designer, another insert query with SELECT @@IDENTITY appended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stored procedures you can get the value as a return value of the stored procedure.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) SO question and answers (Best way to get identity of inserted row?) dealing with the SQL side of this.

Comment: That would be a solution if I were doing this with stored procedures.  However, I'm trying to do this with the typed datasets that I setup with the Visual Studio designer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library, [Kailua - The forgotten methods in the ADO.NET API.](http://kailua.codeplex.com/) , that does provide this and additional metadata for the top 5 vendors. This info is vendor specific.

Wrap your connection in a `net.windward.utils.ado.WrCommand` and use the `ExecuteInsert` function.

Comment: Does the library you linked answer the OP's question, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes. He wants a way to get the value of the primary key just inserted and Kailua has a call to give him that information. He can either use the library or read the code for the Sql Server driver to see how it is done specifically for Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

> **You need to tell your table's table-adapter to refresh the
>   data-table after update/insert operation.
>   This is how you can do that.**

1. Open the properties of **TableAdapter -> Default Select Query -> Advnaced options**. and Check the option of **Refresh the data table**. Save the adapter now. Now when you call update on table-adapter, the **data-table will be updated [refreshed] after the update/insert operation** and will reflect the latest values from database table. **if the primary-key or any coloumn is set to auto-increment, the data-table will have those latest value post recent update.**
2. Now you can Call the update as TableAdapterObj.Update(ds.dataTable);
3. **Read latest values from the DataTable(ds.dataTable) coloumns and assign respective values into the child table before update/insert**. This will work exactly the way you want.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png)