# Appropriate Uses of the `IDENTITY` in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, identity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

When is it appropriate and how should someone use the different `IDENTITY` key word in T-SQL?

- SELECT @@IDENTITY,
- SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
- SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

From the article

> **SELECT @@IDENTITY**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value
>   produced on a connection, regardless
>   of the table that produced the value,
>   and regardless of the scope of the
>   statement that produced the value.
>   @@IDENTITY will return the last
>   identity value entered into a table in
>   your current session. While @@IDENTITY
>   is limited to the current session, it
>   is not limited to the current scope.
>   If you have a trigger on a table that
>   causes an identity to be created in
>   another table, you will get the
>   identity that was created last, even
>   if it was the trigger that created it.
>
> **SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value
>   produced on a connection and by a
>   statement in the same scope,
>   regardless of the table that produced
>   the value. SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like
>   @@IDENTITY, will return the last
>   identity value created in the current
>   session, but it will also limit it to
>   your current scope as well. In other
>   words, it will return the last
>   identity value that you explicitly
>   created, rather than any identity that
>   was created by a trigger or a user
>   defined function.
>
> **SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value
>   produced in a table, regardless of the
>   connection that created the value, and
>   regardless of the scope of the
>   statement that produced the value.
>   IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope
>   and session; it is limited to a
>   specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns
>   the identity value generated for a
>   specific table in any session and any
>   scope.

Comment: sir, in what case we may face need to access the identity column value?  Practically can you give me an example?

Comment: If you wish to use the Identity value as a Foreign Key, or to use it in your application to load after you have inserted the new object.

Comment: And don't assume that the value returned is correct: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779  Another workaround is to use an OUTPUT clause on your INSERT statement to capture the new identity value(s).

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) has a good reference on this.

In a nutshell,  @@IDENTITY's scope is the current session on the server (you could end up retrieving the wrong IDENTITY value after an INSERT if e.g. there is a trigger on the table that also adds to a table with an IDENTITY column).

SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the last inserted ID *for the current scope*, i.e. will not give you the problem as outlined above.

IDENT_CURRENT is not limited to any session, it returns info at the table-level (the last id generated for that table across any session)