# SQL Server SCOPE_IDENTITY does not run linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two servers that are connected using a linked server. When I run this procedure, it inserts a record one to other and that time I want ID from my second server - how do this?

```
  Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_TransferJob]  
(  
  @JOB_id AS bigint,
  @PartyId as int,
  @Commission as decimal(18,2),
  @myid as varchar(max),
  @ident_out as bigint output
)  
AS
BEGIN  


INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,CompanyId,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate  
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,SubCompanyId,PartyId,
FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId,ViaString) 

SELECT   
FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,null,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,1,@PartyId
,FromOther,ToOther,@JOB_id,@Commission,10,ViaString

FROM Booking  
WHERE Id = @JOB_id  ;
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SET @ident_out = @@IDENTITY

-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking_ViaLocations (  
BookingId,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLocId,ViaLocValue,ViaLocLabel  ) 



SELECT   
@ident_out,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLocId,ViaLocValue,ViaLocLabel  
FROM Booking_ViaLocations  
WHERE BookingId = @JOB_id  

END
return @ident_out

GO
```

SCOPE_IDENTITY() AND @@IDENTITY SHOW NULL VALUE HOW TO GET ID please help me

Comment: Try to extract identity in the procedure and pass it through an output parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708996/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row-in-linked-server

Comment: Instead of an insert statement can you create an insert stored procedure on your other server? Then have it return the identity from SCOPE_IDENTITY as an output parameter. --LOL I just looked at the link posted by @TheGameiswar and it suggests the same thing. :D

Comment: Have you looked at the link posted above? It explains quite clearly a very simple way to accomplish this task.

Comment: @SeanLange i checked and i posted above query but its return 0

Comment: That is because your above query is nothing like the example posted as the answer in the linked question.

Comment: my where show me error

Comment: INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking_ViaLocations (  
    BookingId,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLocId,ViaLocValue,ViaLocLabel  
    where bookingId = @ident_out) 
    how to add where caluse this statement

Answer (score 0):

You can return int values using a stored procedure

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_TransferJob]  
(  
  @JOB_id AS bigint,
  @PartyId as int,
  @Commission as decimal(18,2)
)  
AS
BEGIN  



    INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,
    FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId,ViaString)  

    SELECT   
    FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,FromOther,ToOther,@JOB_id,@Commission,10,ViaString

    FROM Booking  
    WHERE Id = @JOB_id 

RETURN (@@IDENTITY)

END
```

Then when you call your procedure on other server:

```
DECLARE @ident INT;
EXECUTE @ident = stp_TransferJob (plus other parameters)
```

Since it is more common to do this with error codes, you might prefer an output parameter:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_TransferJob]  
(  
  @JOB_id AS bigint,
  @PartyId as int,
  @Commission as decimal(18,2),
  @ident_out as int output
)  
AS
BEGIN  



    INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,
    FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId,ViaString)  

    SELECT   
    FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,FromOther,ToOther,@JOB_id,@Commission,10,ViaString

    FROM Booking  
    WHERE Id = @JOB_id 

SET @ident_out = @@IDENTITY

END
```

Then when you call the procedure you add a declared parameter with an output keyword. Please see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

Comment: I would the output parameter here. The return from a stored procedure is intended to be used to indicate a status of the execution. It is NOT intended to return data. That is what the OUTPUT parameters are for.

Comment: As posted this isn't going to work anyway. You need to get the identity on the remote server. And using @@IDENTITY is very rarely a good choice. SCOPE_IDENTITY is almost always a better choice.

Comment: True, he would have to create a stored procedure on the linked server which will return SCOPE_IDENTITY. Addi, are you permitted to create procedures on the linked server?

Comment: yes. but how to get i for run my other query i edit my post query check

Comment: INSERT INTO [111.163.103.122].Taxi.dbo.booking_ViaLocations ( BookingId,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLo‌​cId,ViaLocValue,ViaL‌​ocLabel where bookingId = @ident_out) how to add where caluse this statement