# How to get identity ID in different database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have 2 databases DB1, DB2 under same instance. 
I have 2 tables in each database like:

```
tab1(id1, ...): --id1 is identity column in DB1
tab2(id2,...) : --id2 is identity column in DB2
```

I have following codes in DB1 SP:

```
use DB1
declare @id2 int;
insert into tab1(...) values (...);
insert into DB2.dbo.tab2(...) values (...);
set @id2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

but I can't get the right value for id2, it is null. 
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are the looking at something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537560/get-identity-from-another-serverlinked-server

Comment: Use GUIDs and then tell the DB what you want the ID to be.

Comment: You code sets `@id2` to last inserted identity of `DB2.dbo.tab2`. What is actually the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a different approach you could try and use the 'output' clause as part of the insert.

```
declare @output table (id int)

insert into DB2.dbo.tab2 (...)
output inserted.id2
into @output
values (...)

select @id2 = id from @output
```

I'm pretty sure this is the syntax for output but I've not tested it.

Comment: Just be careful about assignment to a variable - if the source of the insert is a `SELECT` or `VALUES(),(),()` then you are only getting one of the rows assigned to the variable.

Comment: I got an error like: Msg 405, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_XYZ, A remote table cannot be used as a DML target in a statement which includes an `OUTPUT` clause or a nested DML statement.