# SCOPE IDENTITY not allowed on a REMOTE server?

Tags: sql-server, cursor, scope-identity

I am trying to copy data from 2 tables linked by a foreign key on one server and then inserted them into the master database on another server.

The first table will generate a new `IDENTITY` column and then I want to store this in a variable and insert it into the 2nd table.

I have tried both using internal inserted tables and also `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but receive errors that this is not allowed on a REMOTE server

```
    DECLARE 

    @VisitSourceId  int,
    @SiteDomainId   int,
    @trpUTMid   bigint,
    @FlightPlus bit,
    @StartDate  datetime,
    @CountryId  int,
    @ProvinceId int,
    @Locationid int,
    @PlaceId    int,
    @EstabId    int,
    @CheckInDate    smalldatetime,
    @CheckOutDate   smalldatetime,
    @Rooms  int,
    @Room1Adults    int,
    @Room1Children  int,
    @Room2Adults    int,
    @Room2Children  int,
    @Room3Adults    int,
    @Room3Children  int,
    @OutcomeDate    datetime,
    @OutcomeId  smallint,
    @HotelsFound    smallint,
    @Notes  nvarchar,
    @id bigint

    DECLARE c CURSOR STATIC FOR 

    SELECT t.VisitSourceId, t.SiteDomainId, t.trpUTMid, t.FlightPlus, t.StartDate, t.CountryId, t.ProvinceId, t.Locationid, 
    t.PlaceId, t.EstabId, t.CheckInDate, t.CheckOutDate, t.Rooms, t.Room1Adults, t.Room1Children, t.Room2Adults, t.Room2Children, t.Room3Adults, 
    t.Room3Children, tc.OutcomeDate, tc.OutcomeId, tc.HotelsFound, tc.Notes

    FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl t
    INNER JOIN TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl tc
    ON t.trpUTMid = tc.trpUTMid


    open c
    FETCH FIRST FROM c INTO @VisitSourceId, @SiteDomainId, @trpUTMid, @FlightPlus, @StartDate, @CountryId, @ProvinceId, @Locationid, 
    @PlaceId, @EstabId, @CheckInDate, @CheckOutDate, @Rooms, @Room1Adults, @Room1Children, @Room2Adults, @Room2Children, @Room3Adults, 
    @Room3Children, @OutcomeDate, @OutcomeId, @HotelsFound, @Notes  

    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin

    DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (ID BIGINT)

    INSERT INTO [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl
    (VisitSourceId, SiteDomainId, trpUTMid, FlightPlus, StartDate, CountryId, ProvinceId, Locationid, 
    PlaceId, EstabId, CheckInDate, CheckOutDate, Rooms, Room1Adults, Room1Children, Room2Adults, Room2Children, Room3Adults, 
    Room3Children)

    OUTPUT inserted.searchid into @TmpTable

    SELECT @VisitSourceId, @SiteDomainId, @trpUTMid, @FlightPlus, @StartDate, @CountryId, @ProvinceId, @Locationid, 
    @PlaceId, @EstabId, @CheckInDate, @CheckOutDate, @Rooms, @Room1Adults, @Room1Children, @Room2Adults, @Room2Children, @Room3Adults, 
    @Room3Children


    select top 1 @id = searchid from @tmptable


    INSERT INTO [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl
    (SearchId,
    trpUTMid,
    OutcomeDate,
    OutcomeId,
    HotelsFound,
    Notes)

    SELECT @id,
    @trpUTMid,
    @OutcomeDate,
    @OutcomeId,
    @HotelsFound,
    @Notes


    DELETE FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl WHERE trpUTMid=@trpUTMid
    DELETE FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl WHERE trpUTMid=@trpUTMid

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @VisitSourceId, @SiteDomainId, @trpUTMid, @FlightPlus, @StartDate, @CountryId,
    @ProvinceId, @Locationid, @PlaceId, @EstabId, @CheckInDate, @CheckOutDate, @Rooms, @Room1Adults, @Room1Children,
    @Room2Adults, @Room2Children, @Room3Adults, @Room3Children, @OutcomeDate, @OutcomeId, @HotelsFound, @Notes  
    end

    close c
    deallocate c
```

Answer (score 3):

`@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` are local

are you using a linked server?
check this:
[get @@Identity from another server(linked server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537560/get-identity-from-another-serverlinked-server)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I finally created the script on the target server as a stored procedure, then I could use scope identity. The performance also improved massively, I then configured a new linked server with RPC out enabled and called the procedure remotely. It is not an elegant solution, but its only temporary