# using @@identity afer insert

Tags: sql, insert, identity

I have an insert sql with sql server and then call select @@identity straight after, i am trying to use the identity id with a stored procedure, is this even possible

eg

```
insert into ...
select @@identity

EXEc add 'ss' @@identity
```

thanks 
a

edit---

i basically want to use the value of the id which i'm getting now with

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ;

to use in a query straight after the insert.

Comment: What is your problem ? Have you noticed that Microsoft indicates that @@identity should be replaced by SCOPE_IDENTITY() ? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: You should be _editing_ your question instead of posting follow on questions in comments, or if a completely new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the (now deleted) question in the comments...

It is possible to use `@@IDENTITY` directly in the parameter list of the stored procedure call. For `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (which you should be using to avoid problems if a trigger is later added to the table) this syntax is not allowed you need to use an intermediate variable as below.

```
declare @id int

insert into ...

set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

EXEC AddEmp2 0,@id
```

Comment: thanks, this worked.. i tried this but with select @@identity.. but it didn't work. scope_identity is the way to go.

Comment: @Alessandro - Yes `SELECT @@IDENTITY` wouldn't work you would just use `EXEC AddEmp2 0,@@IDENTITY` (this is of academic interest only though!)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible, though you are probably better off using [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) SO question about the best way to get the identity of an inserted row.