# Help with T-SQL script: Insert record, then use identity of that insert on another statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Just as a preface, I'm not very knowledgeable on T-SQL syntax.

I'd like to create a simple SQL script that will make 3 insert statements.

```
Insert A
Insert B
Insert C
```

Insert A statement's identity or "ID" would be needed in insert B statement.
And both the identities Inserts A & B would be needed in Insert C statement.

Pseudo code would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
VALUES ('blah', 'blah')

INSERT INTO tableB
VALUES (IDENTITY_FROM_A_INSERT, 'foo')

INSERT INTO tableC
VALUES (IDENTITY_FROM_A_INSERT, IDENTITY_FROM_B_INSERT)
```

How would I go about writing this script?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) after each insert in order to get the identity of the inserted row (in the current session).

I have used two variables to capture the two identities and then insert them into the third table:

```
DECLARE @Id1 INT
DECLARE @Id2 INT

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('blah', 'blah')

SET @Id1 = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (IDENTITY_FROM_A_INSERT, 'foo')

SET @Id2 = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO tableC VALUES (@Id1, @Id2)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm nuts, but isn't the syntax actually `select @Id1 = scope_identity()`?

Comment: @DanEsparza - that is also valid syntax.

Comment: Or use the OUTPUT variable if you will be inserting multiple records in the first insert.

Answer (score 2):

`scope_identity()` is perfect for integer identifiers on single-record insertions (+1 to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5148010/621962) btw). However, if you find yourself using a guid/[uniqueidentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ([`newsequentialid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`newid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), etc) or inserting multiple records at once, you'll need something a little different:

```
declare @id uniqueidentifier;
-- Table variable for storing your newly inserted identifiers:
declare @NewlyInsertedIds table 
(
   [Id] uniqueidentifier
);

insert [MyTable]
(
   [Blah1]
  ,[Blah2]
)
-- in the output clause you can access the inserted/deleted pseudo tables:
ouptut inserted.[Id]
into @NewlyInsertedIDs
(
   [Id]
)
values
(
   'Blah'
  ,'Blah'
);

select
 @id = [Id]
from @NewlyInsertedIds;
```

Check out [the OUTPUT Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.