# Syntax error on DECLARE

Tags: mysql, syntax

I want to use the serial of an insert directly in a next insert.

Based on [Help with T-SQL script: Insert record, then use identity of that insert on another statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147989/help-with-t-sql-script-insert-record-then-use-identity-of-that-insert-on-anoth) I execute the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @Id1 BIGINT
DECLARE @Id2 BIGINT
INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total) VALUES (10, 10, 10)
SET @Id1 = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO places (x, y, z, speed) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 10)
SET @Id2 = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset) VALUES ('Test', @Id1, 'test', @Id2, 17)
```

This give me a syntax error and I can't find anything wrong with my DECLARE.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @Id1 BIGINT
DECLARE @Id2 BIGINT INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total)' at line 1
```

It seems that DECLARE in MySQL can only be used in a BEGIN..END. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Also SCOPE_IDENTITY is replace with LAST_INSERT_ID().

This is my new query:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @Id1 BIGINT;
DECLARE @Id2 BIGINT;

INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total) VALUES (10, 10, 10);
SET @Id1 = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO places (x, y, z, speed) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 10);
SET @Id2 = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset);
VALUES ('Test', @Id1, 'test', @Id2, 17);

END
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: No need to Select from the scope, its an output, Just remove the SELECT - `SET @Id1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Can you please post the full error message and the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: The error indicates you are using `MySQL` but the code you are trying to run against it is `SQL Server` Syntax; I think in MySQL `;` after each line is mandatory also there is no `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in MySQL you should probably use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead. ([from this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql))

Comment: I changed SCOPE_IDENTITY with LAST_INSERT_ID. Same problem.
I also tried adding the ;. Same problem.
I tried adding BIGINT(20) as data type. Same problem.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Comment: did you add extra brackets to `LAST_INSERT_ID`? i.e. `SET @Id1 = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: I edited my question with the last tries and my tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [you cannot declare and use variables outside triggers/procedures/functions or events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954385/2186023). So you can also not work around this by just writing `BEGIN...END` around it.

Since you need two different ID values in one select-statement you could either wrap this into a stored procedure (that should circumvent the issue of not being able to declare variables) or just use the `MAX`-value of ID in both columns in your final insert-statement.
*(this of course assumes you have `auto_increment` enabled or at least ascending IDs in both tables)*

So in essence you should be able to make it work if you replace your whole code with:

```
INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total) VALUES (10, 10, 10);

INSERT INTO places (x, y, z, speed) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 10);

INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset)
VALUES ('Test', (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM doses), 'test', (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM places), 17);
```

You should also wrap this in an transaction to be safe that no other IDs have been inserted in the meantime.

Comment: Could you remove the ; after INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset);

Answer (score 0):

its just a syntax error.

SELECT @ID1 = SCOPEIDENTITY() will do you I think

Answer (score -1):

Seems issue with setting @Id1 and @Id2

```
    DECLARE @Id1 BIGINT
    DECLARE @Id2 BIGINT

    INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total) VALUES (10, 10, 10)
    SET @Id1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO places (x, y, z, speed) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 10)
    SET @Id2 =SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset) 
    VALUES ('Test', @Id1, 'test', @Id2, 17)
```

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that the question title is wrong? I see that you corrected an issue that should have been corrected but for that particular thing the error should have been `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.` not `Syntax error on DECLARE` shouldn't it?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: I don't see any issue in variable declaration, I have point out the place it can go wrong!!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I also double checked my column names but they seem right. Also, then SQL won't give a syntax error on line 1.
The same solution was pointed out in the comments of the answer of the linked thread. And it seems that both SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() and SCOPE_IDENTITY() are correct.

Comment: @Milan: See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8579/1) do you have the primary key setup correct with the identity??

Comment: The primary keys of doses and places are both SERIAL, so BIGINT(20).
The values in measurements are also BIGINT(20).
How do set up this identity in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html
It seems DECLARE can only be used in a BEGIN...END statement in MySQL.

Comment: @Milan: Ohh, are you using `MySQL`?? I thought it's `sql-server`. Please update your question with correct tags, its misleading !!!