# Return ID from insert statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

I have an INSERT statement e.g.

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT_PROFILE(PATIENT_NAME, OTHER_NAME, AGE, SEX, PHONE_NO, MOB_NO,          CAT_NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES(@PAT_NAME, @OTHER_NAME, @AGE, @SEX, @PHONE, @MOB, @CAT_NAME, @ADD)
```

Now I want to get the patient_id that is present in PATIENT_PROFILE. Is there any way that the insert statement returns the PATIENT_ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Scope_Identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

So:

```
declare @IdInserted int
INSERT INTO PATIENT_PROFILE(PATIENT_NAME, OTHER_NAME, AGE, SEX, PHONE_NO, MOB_NO,          CAT_NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES(@PAT_NAME, @OTHER_NAME, @AGE, @SEX, @PHONE, @MOB, @CAT_NAME, @ADD)
set @IdInserted = Scope_Identity()
```