# multiple interdependable queries in one button click

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my application I had a form where i have to do more than one database transaction  within a single button click
ie 
When I click button

Query 1  >>>insert designation values to Designation table

query 2.  >>select query to get the primary key of last entered designation.... ie .the auto number against which the above insert query inserts

query 3 >> inset data into another table with the primary key recvd from above

query 4 .>> update another table with the primary Key Above

If any of the query fails or any exception occur The others shouldnot work

now I am trying to do it using try catch and deleting prevoius insertions if exception occurs...

Is there any good Ideas as I am new to sql server 2008

Comment: Using transactions is Your answer. Please post the code for the "button_click". It will enable answering Your question more easy.

Comment: You can code all of the above into a single stored procedure.

Comment: can you pls give a link to such a prodedure using multiple queries

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, wrap all these operations into a single transaction, instead of using separate transaction for each of them. The "atomicity" part of the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties of transactions will ensure either all or none of the operations will succeed, and you can never have a partial result.

If you are using ADO.NET, you'll be using [BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.begintransaction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction.commit%28v=vs.100%29) for that.

BTW, you should not do the step 2 - what if a concurrent client inserts a row (and commits) after your step 1 but before you had a chance to execute step 2? You'll get the wrong PK. It's better to [directly get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655/533120) the PK generated in step 1.