# Getting the identity row value for an Insert operation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

All the years I've played with SQL, and I never thought to ask this question.

If I am adding (inserting) a row into a table, and it has an identity column, how might I retrieve the identity for this new row? I am keen on hearing a solution to this, as I fear I may be operating on a database with some very similar or duplicate rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function to obtain the last inserted identity in the current scope.

Comment: Hmm. And if I pair up an Insert statement with a Select statement, I may get my identity. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main functions/ways how to retrieve the value of IDENTITY column. Please follow the first link to brief explanation. The second (MSDN) provides clear examples and comparison:

- [http://blog.sqlauthority.com/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

Three ways how to get identity: *`@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')`*

While `@@IDENTITY` is most likely "the-most-often-used", because of its implementation it does not have to always return expected identity value. read more [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)