# SQL Server error.Explicit value for Identity Column....can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create procedure, which is generating an error stating

An explicit value for the identity column in table `tblRegisterUser` can only be specified when a column list is used and `IDENTITY_INSERT is ON`.

I tried to surround insert statement with `INDENTITY_INSERT to ON`,but that too doesn't work. am I missing anything or is it an error with the sub query which i included?

Following is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertUserRegister
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50),
    @Designation nvarchar(50),
    @Department nvarchar(50),
    @IsAdmin bit
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblRegisterUser Values
    (
        @FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password,@Designation,@Department,@IsAdmin
    )
    DECLARE @UID INT
    SET @UID = @@IDENTITY
    INSERT INTO tblLogin(Username,Password,UID,IsAdmin) 
    Values(@Username, @Password, @UID,(SELECT IsAdmin FROM tblRegisterUser WHERE     Username=@Username AND Password=@Password))
END
```

Comment: "*that too doesn't work*" is not a valid SQL Server error message.

Comment: What is the `create table` for `tblRegisterUser`?

Comment: Unless there's a trigger changing the behaviour of your first insert, or you're allowing multiple people to have the same usernames (and, incidentally, passwords), what's the point of the `(SELECT IsAdmin FROM tblRegisterUser ...` from the second `INSERT`? Why not just `@IsAdmin` again?

Answer (score 2):

If the structure of the `tblRegisterUser` table is something like

```
ID int primary_key autoincrement
FirstName varchar
LastName varchar 
Username varchar
Password varchar
Designation varchar
Department varchar
IsAdmin bit
```

than this statement is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO tblRegisterUser Values
(
    @FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password, 
    @Designation,@Department,@IsAdmin
)
```

You should use an explicit column list to specify the columns:

```
INSERT INTO tblRegisterUser 
(  FirstName, LastName, Username, Password,
   Designation, Department, IsAdmin) 
VALUES 
(
    @FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password, 
    @Designation,@Department,@IsAdmin
)
```

This way the ID field is automatically populated, and the `@@Identity` statement should return it correctly.

---

That said, SQL Server [has a few functions](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) that return the generated ID for the last rows, each with it's own specific strengths and weaknesses.

Basically:

- `@@IDENTITY` works if you do not use triggers
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` works for the code you explicitly called.
- `IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)` works for a specific table, across all scopes.

In almost all scenarios `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is what you need, and it's a good habit to use it, opposed to the other options.
A good discussion on the pros and cons of the approaches is also available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row).

*copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211011/does-every-record-has-an-unique-field-in-sql-server/14211177#14211177)*

Comment: Thanks, its working now, actually it is an identity column, but my while creating tblRegisterUser I missed a column, I must have had done some trail and errors before posting :(. sorry for posting such a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertUserRegister 
(
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Username NVARCHAR(50),
    @Password NVARCHAR(50),
    @Designation NVARCHAR(50),
    @Department NVARCHAR(50),
    @IsAdmin BIT
)
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.tblRegisterUser (FirstName, LastName, Username, [Password], Designation, Department, IsAdmin)
    SELECT @FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password, @Designation, @Department, @IsAdmin

    DECLARE @ID BIGINT
    SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblLogin ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.tblLogin (UserName, [password], [uid], IsAdmin)
    SELECT @Username, @Password, @ID, IsAdmin 
    FROM tblRegisterUser 
    WHERE UserName = @Username 
        AND [password] = @Password

    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblLogin OFF;

END
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now, actually it is an identity column, but my while creating tblRegisterUser I missed a column, I must have had done some trail and errors before posting :(. sorry for posting such a silly question.