# SELECT then UPDATE those records and then return them in STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a SELECT to get a list of ID's, do an update based on those ID's and then return those records.

Something like this I guess, I just do not know the syntax:

```
  SELECT WebHookLogIDs = FROM WebHookLog 
                WHERE Processing=0
                    AND Processed=0
                        AND Paused=0
                            ORDER BY FailCount ASC, WebHookLogID DESC

    UPDATE WebHookLog
        SET Processing = 1
            WHERE WebHookLogID IN(WebHookLogIDs)

    SELECT * FROM WebHookLog 
            WHERE WebHookLogID IN(WebHookLogIDs)
```

Comment: I believe you can also try and do an `OUTPUT UPDATE`. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think its better to put data in **Temp table**, than insert data in it

because at the last you want to return those record back , so you need to use temp table

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (WebHookLogIDs INT)

Insert into @Table1(WebHookLogIDs )
SELECT WebHookLogIDs  FROM WebHookLog 
                WHERE Processing=0
                    AND Processed=0
                        AND Paused=0
                            ORDER BY FailCount ASC, WebHookLogID DESC

    UPDATE WebHookLog
        SET Processing = 1
            WHERE WebHookLogID IN( select WebHookLogIDs from @Table1)

    SELECT * FROM WebHookLog 
            WHERE WebHookLogID IN(select WebHookLogIDs from @Table1)
    DROP TABLE @Table1
```

Comment: so does @Table1 just go away after the query has run?

Comment: @Slee - yes its temp table it will go once it get exeucted but you can drop it ..by writing drop table statement

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `UPDATE` with `SELECT` with the same SQL Statement. You can however, `UPDATE` with `JOIN` instead of selecting the ID's like this:

```
UPDATE w1
SET w1.Processing = 1
FROM WebHookLog w1
INNER JOIN WebHookLog w2  ON w1.WebHookLogID = w2.WebHookLogID 
                         AND w2.Processing    = 0
                         AND w2.Processed     = 0
                         AND w2.Paused        = 0;
```

Later, you can do another `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Sorry this is a Stored Procedure

Comment: @Slee OK, Sorry, then put the `SELECT` clause after it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE WebHookLog
SET PROCESSING = 1
WHERE WebHookLogID IN ( SELECT WebHookLogIDs = FROM WebHookLog 
                WHERE Processing=0
                    AND Processed=0
                        AND Paused=0)

SELECT * FROM WebHookLog 
WHERE WebHookLogID IN(WebHookLogIDs)
```