# Slow SQLite update with Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I've built and it gets both added to and updated on a weekly basis. The issue I have is the update seems to take a very long time. (Roughly 2 hours without the transaction table). I'm hoping there is a faster way to do this. What the script does is read from a CSV and updates the database line by line through a loop

An example data entry would be:
`JohnDoe123  018238e1f5092c66d896906bfbcf9abf5abe978975a8852eb3a78871e16b4268`

The Code that I use is

```py
#updates reported table    
def update_sha(conn, sha, ID, op):
    
    sql_update_reported = 'UPDATE reported SET sha = ? WHERE ID = ? AND operator = ?'
    sql_update_blocked = 'UPDATE blocked SET sha = ? WHERE ID = ? AND operator = ?'
    sql_update_trans = 'UPDATE transactions SET sha = ? WHERE ID = ? AND operator = ?'
    
    data = (sha, ID, op)
    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_update_reported, data)
    cur.execute(sql_update_blocked, data)
    cur.execute(sql_update_trans, data)
    conn.commit()
    
def Count(conn):
    #Creates a dataframe with the Excel sheet information and ensures them to
    #be strings
    df = pd.DataFrame()    
    df = pd.read_excel("Count.xlsx", engine='openpyxl',converters={'ID':str})
    
    #Runs through the DataFrame once for reported
    for i in df.index:
        ID = df['ID'][i]
        Sha = df['Sha'][i]
        op = df['op'][i]
        print(i)
        with conn:
            update_dupi(conn, Sha, ID, op)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = create_connection(database)
    print("Updating Now..")
    Count(conn)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: It's slow because you're making individual transactions as you iterate the df. You will want to use `executemany`

Comment: You're also running so many dead queries (dead because the values don't match up). This setup works by accident, not design. I was going to try and unpick it in a quick answer but this is going to take more effort than I first thought

Comment: @roganjosh yeah I'm not sure a great way to check it because the CSV only contains lines that have the update value where as the database may not have them

Comment: It's not even that. You're just on a wing-and-prayer that the WHERE fails

Comment: I guess that's true yeah

Comment: @roganjosh would you happen to know if there's a way to say select the rows I want to update then update them? I did find this suggestion just not sure it would work in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338148/select-then-update-those-records-and-then-return-them-in-stored-procedure