# How to manually replicate two tables with identity fields

Tags: sql-server, triggers

-- DUPLICATE OF [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) --

Well, I got an hard time finding a good title for this one.

I have two tables, with microsoft SQL server. Here's the structure:

```
TableA ( Id identity, Name varchar(20))
TableB ( Id identity, Name varchar(20))
Mapping ( IdTableA int, IdTableB int)
```

On TableA, I have an After Insert trigger. I want to "replicate" the insert into TableB, gets the new Ids and insert the mapping between the TableA's id and the TableB's id into the table Mapping.

I have no problem with inserting the data into TableB... but I have an hard time finding how to create a "map" between the two Ids...

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I know I can do this using Cursor or a While loop, but EVERYBODY says that's an option to totally avoid.

Comment: I found the answer elsewhere in SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row