# Retrieve last inserted GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need the last inserted row **GUID** at the time of page loading in ASP.NET. I tried with a stored procedure, but at the time of insertion I am getting how to use that value in the page load procedure like this:

```
USE [emp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procTestTableInsert]    Script Date: 3/12/2014 5:55:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procTestTableInsert]
(
    @name varchar(50)
)
AS
    DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

SELECT @id = NEWID()-- Get a new unique identifier to insert

INSERT 
    testTable1(id,name)
VALUES
    (@id,@name)

SELECT @id  

exec procTestTableInsert sree
```

Comment: Missing `BEGIN` and `END` around your stored procedure code?

Comment: Why do you need to query to get the last GUID inserted when you have it in your proc already?  Can you not just pass it back to the calling app?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Why include links to Wikipedia. There are tags with tag wikis already.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) you should be able to query  [`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx).

From the MSDN documentation:

A. Returning the last identity value generated for a specified table
The following example returns the last identity value generated for the Person.Address table in the AdventureWorks2012 database.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('Person.Address') AS Current_Identity;
GO
```

Note:  This assumes that your GUID is the row ID.  If it's not the row ID, this wont work.  In which case, I'd recommend either storing the last ID in a temp table in SQL (update your stored proc to save the guid) or have you application cache it.