# Getting key from new record before calling SaveChanges in MVC not using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I am using MVC5 without entity framework, and want to retrieve the key from a newly inserted record before calling SaveChanges. This is because I need the key to work as a foreign key in a different record.

Here's the pseudo code to better explain what I want to do:

```
1) Create record for Person

2) var newPersonId = newly created personId from Person record

3) Create record for Employee, set its personId (foreign key) to be equal to newPersonId

4) Person.SaveChanges
   Emplyee.SaveChanges
```

Thus, the problem is step 2.

I read that the way to do this when using entity framework is to setup a relationsship in the model with [ForeignKey("xxx")], and entity framework will take of things. But as I don't use entity framework, how can I do this?

Comment: And why you cant save person and then get its ID before aving and creating employee Record?

Comment: If you use GUIDs as PK, you can create a new GUID, and create person with this id.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42655/809357

Comment: If you are not using EF, what is up with step 4 and "save changes"?  Step 1 and 3 execute the INSERT..?

Comment: @JleruOHeP: Because if Employee fails to save, I want to be able to rollback Person as well.

Comment: @trailmax: I prefer using a normal integer value automatically incremented by the database.

Comment: In this case check the answer I've linked above. There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using EF how come you have SaveChanges.

Ok, Any way you can use TransactionScope.

```
using (TransactionScope transactionscope = new TransactionScope()){
     //some other code....

     Person.SaveChanges();
     Employee.PersonId = Person.Id;
     Employee.SaveChanges()

     //if any exception rised here, all the save changes will be reverted
     transactionscope.Complete();
    }
```

and you need to have `System.Transactions` included