# Getting the ID of last inserted row from SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this code in my application, and it's working fine. 
I didn't use SCOPE_IDENTITY as I heard its old method. 
Can anybody check if I am doing the right method for getting last inserted Record ID ? 
Will this work If I add a transaction ?

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, Description) OUTPUT INSERTED.UserID " +
    "VALUES (@pUserName, @pDescription); ", con))
{


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUserName" ,userNameTxt.Text ); 

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDescription" , userDescription.Text); 



    int lastID = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());

    foreach (ListViewItem lit in ListView3.Items)
    {
        HiddenField gid = (HiddenField)lit.FindControl("ListGroupID");
        int gidVal = 0;
        if (gid != null && gid.Value != null && !Int32.TryParse(gid.Value, out gidVal)) gidVal = 0;
        if (gidVal != 0)
        {
            com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO App_UserGroups (UserID, GroupID) " +
                "VALUES ( " +   lastID  + ", " + gidVal + ")";
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `mysql` tag by the way? `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is not old. Who said that? Have you ever try to use it?

Comment: if your performing this directly after an insert, you can use  IDENT_CURRENT('TableName') and return that value

Comment: @SonerGönül sorry. I edited it

Comment: @horHAY But Its not limited to the scope right ? I will get the last inserted ID from Other users too .

Comment: @SonerGönül I tried but, I had to use a select statement along with the insert statement, which I feel a bad practice.

Comment: By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You need to execute Insert and get the SCOPE_IDENTITY in the same scope. It can be a transaction, Procedure, PL Block etc. Check the definition https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx . If you make 2 round trips to database to insert and then get identity, nothing can guarantee the correct identity, unless there is only one user using the system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scope_identity:

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, Description) " + " VALUES (@pUserName, @pDescription);" + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)" , con))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same question a few days ago too and i've found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) explaining every way of retrieving the inserted id from the table.

To answer your question, both `OUTPUT_CLAUSE` and `IDENT_CURRENT` can be used in this scenario even if you add a transaction but i would recomment `IDENT_CURRENT` because **an OUTPUT clause will return rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and is rolled back**.

Use it as @horHay suggested in the comments as :

`using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, Description)"+ 
    "VALUES (@pUserName, @pDescription) SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('App_Users'); ", con))`

I would **not suggest** `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `@@IDENTITY` because it **may return wrong values** (null) if you're not using **SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2** or higher ( [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) - last row from the page.) especially for your requirement (inserting the value in some other table).