# How can I run a query inside of my EF code first migration

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having issues adding a Foreign Key to link 2 existing tables together.  `Table A` has data, and I need it to reference `Table B` (which also has data).

I will need to insert a row (or rows) into `Table B` which `Table A` will reference.

In this case it is acceptable to insert a row into `Table B` and then use that as the default value for the migration. That would require that I know the ID of the row that I'm inserting.

I think that I can handle everything except figuring out the ID of the row that I insert into `Table B`.

Is it possible to return data inside of Migrations?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, there is a very simple way to add a foreign key inside a migration `AddForeignKey("TableA", "TableB_Id", "TableB", "Id");` you could also do it in SQL by running `SQL("[your query goes here]")` but it is void, so no result is to be expected

Comment: I edited my question.  I know how to add the foreign key, but I don't know how to add it with existing (or even new!) data

Comment: I think you will have to use SQL to do what you want

Comment: You could try scope_identity() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2013/12/23/EntityFramework6CodeFirstMigrations.aspx

Comment: That's basically exactly what I'd like to do, but I don't think I can run queries inside of a DbMigration file