# How create a row and take his id at the same time in sql server and c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a simple problem but cant find a solution:

I'm creating a row in my table client, but I don't know how recovery the id of the table that I just created, for example:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsert_client]
@idclient int output,
@name varchar(20),
@surname varchar(40),
as
insert into client(name,surname)
values (@name,@surname)
```

here I insert a client, now I want recovery that exact same idclient to insert "products" with it without have to manually search this client , I tried recovering the last row of the client table but I realise that if more than one person is using the same database in different computers it can be a problem, so I need create a client and recovery his id at the same time (it is an assumption I don't know). Im using sql server and Visual studio with c#

sorry for my bad English and thanks for the attention

edit-------------------
solution:

```html
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsert_client]
@idclient int output,
@name varchar(20),
@surname varchar(40)
as
insert into client(name,surname)
values (@name,@surname)
Select @@IDENTITY as newId;


them in my c# code:

rpta= SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to get an auto-increment primary key ID back after doing an insert? Can you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the `OUTPUT` clause.  Here is an example that just captures the new id:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsert_client] (
    @idclient int output,
    @name varchar(20),
    @surname varchar(40)
)
as
begin
    declare @output table (idclient int);

    insert into client(name, surname)
         output inserted.idclient into @output;
        values (@name, @surname);

    select *
    from @output;
end;  -- spinsert_client
```

Comment: that looks good but how I convert that output into a string in my c# programm? edited my answer.Im triying do it with EXECUTESCALAR but always get and error

Comment: You would either use a function or pass in an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code you have somewhere a sql Statement defined:

```
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO ... (field list) OUTPUT INSERTED.yourfieldwithid values (value list) ";
```

and use it with ExecuteScalar() for getting the result value (I assume you know how to use Connection and command object)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO client" +
             " (name, surname)" +
             " VALUES (@Name, @Surname);" +
             " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

using (var dbconn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here") )
using (var dbcm = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn) )
{
    dbcm.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "name value";
    dbcm.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = "surname value";

    dbconn.Open();
    var insertedID = (int)dbcm .ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check  [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) explaining every way of retrieving the inserted id from the table.

To answer your question, both `OUTPUT_CLAUSE` and `IDENT_CURRENT` can be used in this scenario but i would recomment `IDENT_CURRENT` because **an OUTPUT clause will return rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and is rolled back**.

Use it like:

`using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO cient(name, surname)"+ 
    "VALUES (@Name, @Surname) SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('client'); ", con))`

I would **not suggest** `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `@@IDENTITY` because it **may return wrong values** (null) if you're not using **SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2** or higher ( [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) - last row from the page.) especially for your requirement (inserting the value in some other table).