# How to design audit dimension in the data mart using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

**Goal**

I aim to create SSIS (ETL) Template that enables audit functionality (Audit Dimension). I've discovered a few ways to implement audit dimension that are described below with some reference links below:

[SEQUENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

[Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

### [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

**Environment:**

- There are millions of rows in a fact tables and packages run a few
  times a day.
- Incremental ETL gets thousands of rows.
- SQL Server 2012 BI edition is used for the BI solution.

Simplified Schema of DimAudit table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dw].[DimAudit] (
       [AuditKey] [int] IDENTITY(1 ,1) NOT NULL,
       [ParentAuditKey] [int] NOT NULL,
       [TableName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Unknown'),
       [PackageName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Unknown'),
       [ExecStartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT ( getdate()),
       [ExecStopDate] [datetime] NULL,
       [SuccessfulProcessingInd] [char] (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('N'),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DimAudit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
       [AuditKey] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dw].[DimAudit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DimAudit_ParentAuditKey] FOREIGN KEY( [ParentAuditKey])
REFERENCES [dw]. [DimAudit] ( [AuditKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dw].[DimAudit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DimAudit_ParentAuditKey]
GO
```

---

**Primary Key Option:**

Primary key is generated in the audit table and then AuditKey is queried.

[image]

*Task: Master SQL Audit Generates Key (SQL Task)*

```
INSERT INTO [dw].[DimAudit]
           (ParentAuditKey
           ,[TableName]
           ,[PackageName]
           ,[ExecStartDate]
           ,[ExecStopDate]
           ,[SuccessfulProcessingInd])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'Master Extract Package'
           ,?
           ,?
           ,?
           ,'N')

SELECT AuditKey 
FROM [dw].[DimAudit] 
WHERE TableName = 'Master Extract Package' and ExecStartDT = ?  
/*
Last Parameter: ParameterSystem::StartTime
Result Set populates User::ParentAuditKey
*/
```

*Task: Master SQL Audit End (SQL Task)*

```
UPDATE  [dw]. [DimAudit]
SET    ParentAuditKey = AuditKey
       ,ExecStopDT = SYSDATETIME()
       ,SuccessfulProcessingInd= 'Y'
WHERE   AuditKey = ?

/*
Parameter: User::ParentAuditKey
*/
```

**[SEQUENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) Option:**

The sequence option does not select primary key (AuditKey) but uses logic below to create next available AuditKey.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo . AuditID as INT
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

DECLARE @AuditID INTEGER ;
SET @AuditID = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo. AuditID ;
```

**[Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)**

It feels risky using identity options as ETL packages could be executed in parallel.

**Question**

What is the recommended practice for audit dimension table and managing keys?

Sequence & primary key options do the job; however, I have concerns about the selecting primary key option because package could be executed the same millisecond (in theory) and therefore, a few primary keys would exist. So, Sequence sounds like the best option.

Is anything better I could do to create Audit Dimension for a data mart?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OUTPUT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO [dw].[DimAudit]
       (ParentAuditKey
       ,[TableName]
       ,[PackageName]
       ,[ExecStartDate]
       ,[ExecStopDate]
       ,[SuccessfulProcessingInd])
OUTPUT inserted.AuditKey
VALUES
       (1
       ,'Master Extract Package'
       ,?
       ,?
       ,?
       ,'N')
```

or SCOPE_IDENTITY() which is what I'm personally using:

```
INSERT INTO Meta.AuditDim (
      Date,
      UserName,
      Source,
      SourceType,
      AuditType,
      ExecutionId,
      ExecutionHost,
      ParentAuditKey,
      FileID
    )
VALUES (
      GETDATE(),
      CURRENT_USER,
      @Source,
      @SourceType,
      @AuditType,
      @ExecutionId,
      @ExecutionHost,
      @ParentAuditKey,
      @FileID
    );

SELECT AuditKey FROM Meta.AuditDim WHERE AuditKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```