# accessing dataset tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wonder what is the right approach for getting tables from dataset.

should i return the data within my procedure with select statement?

this is how i do it ,it works but i am not sure this is the right way.

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

and this is how i access my table:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).ToString()
```

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is a scalar, not a table. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am calling a procedure that creates a user,in my c# code i want to get the last number in my table, at first i tried to access my table like ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).ToString() but then i realised that i get no table so i put SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() in my procedure

Comment: You do not want the “last number in my table” you want the ID of the inserted row. Use an `OUTPUT` clause as explained in [Best way to get identity of inserted row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using DataRow and looping though the set

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0])
{
    string someData = row["keyname"].ToString();
}
```

I'm unsure of your question in the first place. But MSDN has a lot of ducumentation, and you can read up on more data structures that can help with DataTables and how to access them. And even query the DataTable with linq like this

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
select myRow;
```

Comment: the problem is that ds.Tables[0] is null if i don't put SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() in my procedure

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you're even filling the table, you can look into using DataAdapter and calling the fill() method and passing it the Command you're using

Comment: i'll try using DataAdapter.