# Update table row with inserted identity ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products 
        ( Code , 
          ProducerCode , 
          CustomerId , 
          EanCode , 
          ChangedDateTime , 
          ChangedById , 
          Deleted  
        ) 
SELECT  Code , 
        ProducerCode , 
        CustomerId , 
        EanCode , 
        GETDATE(), 
        GETDATE(),
        0 
FROM dbo.BulkProducts 
WHERE ProductId is NULL AND BulkProducts.BulkId = @BulkId
```

The `Products` table has an IDENTITY `ID` column, which is assigned automatically on insert. What I want to achieve is, after the insertion in `Products`, have the assigned `ID` of the product in the row from `BulkProducts`. I have read a bit about`@@IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY` but I cannot seem to get it to work for my example. Any help appreciated. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Assuming the select returns more then one row, you will need to add an output clause to the insert statement to get the recently entered record ids.

Comment: Mind sharing a short example on the syntax?

Comment: A clear example is provided in the MSDN reference.  Take a look at this and see if it helps.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: sounds like a job for the Trigger?

Comment: Possible dupe of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `Output` clause, like this -

```
DECLARE @OutProduct TABLE 
(
    ProductID INT,
    Code INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Products 
        ( Code , 
          ProducerCode , 
          CustomerId , 
          EanCode , 
          ChangedDateTime , 
          ChangedById , 
          Deleted  
        ) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Code INTO @OutProduct (ProductID, Code)
SELECT  Code , 
        ProducerCode , 
        CustomerId , 
        EanCode , 
        GETDATE(), 
        GETDATE(),
        0 
FROM dbo.BulkProducts 
WHERE ProductId is NULL AND BulkProducts.BulkId = @BulkId
```

So Now all your inserted data are in `@OutProduct` table. Now you can update your BulkProducts table using that temp table like below.

```
UPDATE bprod 
    SET productID = tmp.ProductID
FROM BulkProducts bprod
INNER JOIN @OutProduct tmp  
   ON bprod.Code = tmp.Code
WHERE bprod.ProductId is NULL AND bprod.BulkId = @BulkId
```

Comment: The `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @OutProduct (ProductID, BulkId)` will insert both the current just-inserted-ID and BulkId?

Comment: Ok but as you can see the `BulkId` field isn't getting inserted, so I don't think is accessible from `INSERTED`.. I've tried `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, BulkProducts.BulkId INTO @OutProduct (ProductID, BulkId)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, you changed it with `Code`, but I still need the `BulkId` :D

Comment: @iuliu.net: I understand. See my update query again at the last. I have added `Where` clause. I think now no need to BulkID

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this cannot be solved without a `MERGE`. The final solution looks like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Products
USING dbo.BulkProducts AS src
    ON 1 = 0 -- Never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(EanCode, ChangedDateTime, ChangedById, Deleted)
    VALUES(src.EanCode, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 0)
OUTPUT
    inserted.Id,
    src.Id
INTO @OutProduct;
```

And like this, my `@OutProduct` table contains tuples of `BulkProductId` and `ProductId` which I can then use to update my `BulkProducts` table.