# Returning an identity after insert, then using identity value in another insert

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-server-2014, identity

To preface, I have to do a bulk insert in a `patients` table that looks similar to:

```
pid     | FirstName       | LastName
-------------------------------------------
10     | John             | Cena
11     | Eric             | Bischoff
12     | Vince            | Russo
```

My insert statement looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO patients (FirstName, LastName) 
OUTPUT inserted.pid
VALUES ('Seth', Rollins');
```

This returns the latest `pid`, but how would I use that returned identity in another insert statement in a completely different table?

```
INSERT INTO booking (pid, start, end) 
VALUES (inserted.pid, 'XX/XX/XXXX', XX/XX/XXXX');
```

IE:

```
booking_id | pid   | start       | end 
-----------------------------------------
1          | 10    | 08/01/2016  | NULL
2          | 11    | 07/25/2016  | 07/26/2016
```

I am looping through a large .csv file with this first and last name information.

Comment: If you're only inserting a single value at a time you can use Scope_Identity() to get the last identity value created. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), you can use following syntax:

```
DECLARE @out TABLE (pid int);

INSERT INTO patients (FirstName, LastName) 
OUTPUT inserted.pid INTO @out
VALUES ('Seth', 'Rollins');

INSERT INTO booking (pid, start, end) 
VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 pid FROM @out), 'XX/XX/XXXX', 'XX/XX/XXXX');
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Dyl, but your solution returns this result: 

A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
Must declare the scalar variable "@lastPid".

Answer (score 0):

The most transtworthy method will be:

```
declare @ID table (ID int)
declare @someInt int

INSERT INTO patients (FirstName, LastName) 
OUTPUT inserted.pid into into @ID
VALUES ('Seth', 'Rollins');

SELECT @someInt = ID FROM @ID

INSERT INTO booking (pid, start, end) 
VALUES (@someInt , 'XX/XX/XXXX', XX/XX/XXXX');
```