# Is it safe to get the last value of an auto incremented primary key with a select statement?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, concurrency

Let's assume the following simple table in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
   Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Name NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

And the following corresponding class in C#:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Consider now the following `CreatePerson` method (pseudo code):

```
public static Person CreatePerson(string name) {
    ...
    DB.Execute("INSERT INTO Person(Name) VALUES (name)", name);
    int lastId = DB.Get("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Person");
    return new Person {Id = lastId, Name=name};
}
```

This method creates a new person row in the db, builds a new Person object and then it returns the created object that is supposed to contain the database generated Id.

**Is it safe and/or correct (from a concurrency perspective)** to get the last generated Id by using the following SELECT statement?

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Person
```

I am concerned about the following scenario:

1. **USER A** Inserts a `person 1`
2. **USER B** Inserts a `person 2`
3. **USER A** reads the last Id and thinks that it is the Id of `person 1`

**Note that** USER A and USER B here refers to threads handling the two separate queries to the database.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In a distributed system, such information can easily become outdated - what use do you expect out of the value that you get?

Comment: If you want user A to just see his inserted people (or in this case person), you could add a field to the table that indicates which user inserted the person. With a fitting `WHERE` statement added to your `SELECT` you shouldn't have any problems with `MAX(Id)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: No, it is not safe.  SCOPE_IDENTITY() et al exist for this.

Comment: You can get it (or scope_identity) but next moment it's already not valid.

Comment: No, it's not safe.

Comment: please check the edited version

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to get the last identity value inserted by a person on that particular scope, use `Scope_Identity()`.

If you wanted to get the last identity value inserted to a particular table across the scope, you can go with `@@identity`.

If you wanted to get the current identity value of a particular table, use `Ident_Current ('Yourtablename')`.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not safe,you can use this procedure for data insert and get your lastId by using scopre_Identity function

```
create PROCEDURE Your_procedure_for_insert
@Name      VARCHAR(50),
@lastID      INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Person
            (
            Name                
            )
VALUES  
            (
            @Name 
            );

SET @lastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END;
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul Abadin Tuhin but I am interested  in handling the procedural logic in C#.

Comment: I think this link may be helpful for you  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399357(v=vs.110).aspx