# How to safely use current identity as value in insert query

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have a table where one of the columns is a path to an image and I need to create a directory for the record being inserted.

Example:

```
Id | PicPath |<br>
 1 | /Pics/1/0.jpg|<br>
 2 | /Pics/2/0.jpg|
```

This way I can be sure that the folder name is always valid and it is unique (no clash between two records).

Question is: how can I **safely** refer to the current id of the record being insert? Keep in mind that this is a highly concurrent environment, and I would like to avoid multiple trips to the DB if possible.

I have tried the following:

```
insert into Dummy values(CONCAT('a', (select IDENT_CURRENT('Dummy'))))
```

and

```
insert into Dummy values(CONCAT('a', (select SCOPE_IDENTITY() + 1)))
```

The first query is not safe, for when running 1000 concurrent inserts I got 58 'duplicate key' exceptions.

The second query didn't work because SCOPE_IDENTITY() returned the same value for all queries as I suspected.

What are my alternatives here?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: I have, but using output would require partial insert -> get id from output -> update record using it, and I would like to perform a single operation

Comment: @victor the OUTPUT clause is the only guaranteed method for concurrent scenarios. Everything else has concurrency issues.

Comment: victor ...what @i.net said ... if your in a highly concurrent scenario, this is pretty much the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a temporary table to track your inserted ids using [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause

```
INSERT #temp_ids(someval) OUTPUT inserted.identity_column
```

This will get all the inserted ids from your queries. 'inserted' is context safe.