# Insert data from two tables to one table C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, listbox

Hi what is the correct way to insert data from two tables to one table ,so they are 3 tables, my fist table is `Tbl_order` has `Order_ID`and the second `Tbl_Cashier` has `Cashier_ID` and the 3rd is `Tbl_Finalized` has `Order_ID` and `Cashier_ID` . the full design of the tables

Tbl_Cashier

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Cashier] (
    [Cashier_ID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FName]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [MName]      VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [LName]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Address]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [ContactNo]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Age]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [Gender]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Password]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [role]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Cashier_ID] ASC)
);
```

Tbl_order

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_order] (
    [Order_ID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerNo] INT            NOT NULL,
    [OrderName]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Price]      FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
    [Serves_way] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Date]       DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Order_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [Serves_wayFK] FOREIGN KEY ([Serves_way]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Serve] ([Serve_ID])
);
```

Tbl_Finalized

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Finalized] (
    [Finalized_ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Order_ID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [Cashier_ID]   INT NOT NULL,
    [Customer_ID]  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Finalized_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [CashierFK] FOREIGN KEY ([Cashier_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Cashier] ([Cashier_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [CustomerFK] FOREIGN KEY ([Customer_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Customer] ([Customer_ID])
);
```

so when I log in the application I use `Tbl_Cashier` by FName and password
I log in , How to get the `Cashier_ID` that logged in and insert it to `Cashier_ID` in `Tbl_Finalized` ? this is my log in code :

```
private void but_log_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbx_username.Text == "" || Tbx_Password.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide UserName and Password");
                return;
            }
            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from 
                Tbl_Cashier where FName=@username and Password=@password", con))
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbx_username.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Tbx_Password.Text);


                            HabibisGrll.Globals.sss = tbx_username.Text;

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                        this.Hide();
                        HabibisGrll fm = new HabibisGrll();
                        fm.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And from the application I use listboxes to insert the orders to `Tbl_order` i want to insert the `Order_ID` it has been i selected and inserted from `Tbl_order`to `Order_ID` in `Tbl_Finalized`. my code that insert all orders to the database from listbox

```
private void Order()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_order (OrderName,Quantity,Price,Serves_way,Date,CustomerNo) VALUES (@OrderName,@Quantity, @Price,'" + servers + "','" + time1.ToString(format1) + "','" + Globals.order + "' )";
                Globals.order++;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    // Add the length of this text column as third parameter...
                    command.Parameters.Add("OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    command.Parameters.Add("Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
                    command.Parameters.Add("Price", SqlDbType.Money);
                    command.Prepare();

                for (int i = 0; i < lst_OrderName.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    command.Parameters[0].Value = lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.Items[i]);
                    command.Parameters[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(lst_QTY.Items[i]);
                    command.Parameters[2].Value = Convert.ToDouble(lst_Price2.Items[i]);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    /* int totalRows = CustomerNo.Rows.Count;
                       int totalCols = CustomerNo.Columns.Count;

                       string value = CustomerNo.Rows[totalRows - 1][totalCols - 1].ToString();*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in but_log_in_Click you put the data into a dataset, which the first field is the cashiers ID - keep it somewhere safe now you have your logged in ID

Comment: yeap i got your point ill try it and update you ^^ , but how about the `Order_ID` any clue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: the clue of the answer is here as he said ^^ but the 2nd part not sure tho ^^