# Insert query with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server

When i try to insert a value in my database it returns me no error but it inserts me nothing, on sql server it works perfectly.

```
<?php
$serverName = "12.15.88.81";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Dcs", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));

}
if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Dcs_name] (ID,NAME) VALUES (?,?)";
$params = array('11','Ani');
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't use sql-server functions but it looks like you are starting a transaction, you need to commit that for the change to apply. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-commit.php Also, don't execute the query twice, and I'd have the `id` auto-increment.

Comment: check this: best way to find out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

you're right I added commit and it works thank you so much.

```
if( $stmt ) {
     sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
     echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
} else {
     sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
     echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}
```