# T-SQL - Print last Inserted ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a set of data for our app. I am trying to get the iInserted ID to be printed in the messages panel, but nothing seems to work.

```
INSERT INTO ...

DECLARE @ID INTEGER = (SELECT @@Identity);
PRINT @ID;
```

The print is printing nothing at all...

How can I get the `id`.?

I tried with

```
DECLARE @ID INTEGER = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tablename'))
```

and it didn't work either...

**EDIT**: I need to PRINT the ID in the message PANEL, I must not print a table.

Script:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Email)
VALUES ('a', 'a')

DECLARE @id INTEGER = ??
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: i've checked it and it didn't help me to solve my probleme

Comment: Are you sure the record is actually inserted into the table?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure it is inserted

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you working with? Does the `Emplyee` table have an `identity` column?

Comment: Azure so i dont know which version exactly

Comment: No one reading your question knows what "message panel" means, but it is obviously some part of an application. So your question really isn't one about tsql so much as how to get information about the result of your insert statement into your application. And you did not mention anything about your app environment which is why you and everyone else is spinning wheels making tsql suggestions.

Comment: Message panel from Management Studio ? where they write (1 rows affected) How can i call it... when it's called Messages ?

Comment: Does your table have an identity column?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the OUTPUT clause with your insert statement, play with this and see if it helps. This is the more verbose way but it is scoped appropriately and if you are using parallelism is the only guaranteed way.

```
--Create table variable to hold the new IDcreated by insert statement.
DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (ID Int);

--Insert the new record.
INSERT INTO [Whatever].[Table] 
    (ID)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @Inserted 
VALUES
    (ID);

SELECT ID from @Inserted;
```

Comment: What is Inserted? where does it come from?

Comment: You can't output into a scalar variable, only into a table (actual, temporary or variable doesn't matter)

Comment: Good catch, I forgot quickly about this rule, updated and this should work.

Comment: Also, fyi just since you asked, inserted and deleted are special tables created by sql in DML statements you can use which hold the data that was just modified. You can access the entire row of data this way after the fact.

Comment: i get this... Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. That's why i asked you where it come from...

Answer (score 2):

If your table has an IDENTITY column, you should be using

```
DECLARE @ID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Since SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last inserted identity in the scope you're running.

If you have an insert inside a trigger and use the @@IDENTITY variable, you'll have conflicts and you'll get a wrong IDENTITY value.

Comment: It doesnt print the variable after i've put it in ID

Comment: Share the create table statement and the complete insert. Without this, is hard do help.

Comment: added an exemple