# How can I get inserted ID in SQL Server while using SqlClient class?

Tags: sql-server, insert, identity, sqlclient

So this is a continuation of post:
[Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row/6073578#6073578)

That post proposes, and I agree, to use `Inserted` feature to safely return inserted `id` column(s).

While implementing this feature, it seems `SqlClient` of the .net framework does not support this feature, and fails while trying to execute command, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot find either column "INSERTED" or the user-defined function or aggregate "INSERTED.Id", or the name is ambiguous.'

I'm just using:

```
return (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Where the query is:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id 
(Description) 
VALUES (@Description)
```

And the table just contains

```
ID (identity int)
Description (varchar(max))
```

If impossible to do, is there other safe way without using variables in the middle that might affect performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, but you have misplaced the `OUTPUT` clause: it goes after the list of columns and before the `VALUES`, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Description) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id 
VALUES (@Description)
```

Comment: Ah thanks, example I saw didn't contain target columns, didn't noticed that... clearly I need to sleep.