# Add new column 'Aid' to B table and link it to the increment id in A

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I am new to database design. I am trying to create two tables which are linked by 'name' from A table and 'Aname' from table B. But what i want to do is creating a new increment int column 'id' as a representation for 'name' in A table and then add a new column in B called 'Aid' which is the foreign key.

My idea is to first (SQL SERVER)

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by A.name) id, A.* from A;
```

But how can I link this id to 'Aid' in B table?

Or if there is any existing statements for this question?

Thank you!

Comment: I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you can make sense of what your question is. I get a general idea of what you want but what are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: You are not clear. Also please read & act on [mcve]. If you don't have a natural key shared between tables then the database cannot tell you what id value goes with what row in the other table & you cannot update the table(s) en masse. But you can insert to the FK table each time you insert to the PK table: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42648/3404097. But you are not clear. Also if you did clearly state what you mean in one phrase you could google & find this obvious faq. Lack of such research merits downvotes--see the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the columns already defined, you can use `join` in an `update`:

```
update b
    set b.a_id = a.a_id
    from b join
         a
         on b.name = a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first look up how to add an auto-increment column to an existing dataset, which there are a number of resources for online. You can find one that is specific to your version of SQL Server. Then you can look into joining your B table to your A table on that. Don't add data to a table that is intended to be joined on a ROW_NUMBER result though. This is not good database design.