# How to add if else statement to check if data was entered into SQL Server database and display a message

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a program which enters inputted details into a SQL Server database, the program is working well and data will go into SQL Server. I am sending `customerID`, `customerName`, `CustomerAddress`, `CustomerAddedDate` to the SQL Server database.

How do I go about creating an `if...else` statement to display a message box to the user to inform them if data was inserted successfully or not, and if not, why not.

Also, how can I automatically have the next available `customerID` (which is the integer primary key in the SQL Server database) show up automatically in the `customerID` textbox?

I imagine a code which reads from the `customerID` column in SQL Server database and then add +1 to it and setting that to the properties of `customerID` aka `textbox1` but perhaps there is a better idea?

My program:

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS02;Initial Catalog=Greenwich_Butcher;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string dat = "Insert into [CustomerDetails](CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerAddedDate) Values('" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Text) + "')";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(dat, con);
        con.Open();
        int rowsAffected = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rowsAffected > 0)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted succesfully");
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record not inserted succesfully");
        }
        con.Close();

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh so biting my tongue...

Comment: Only one question per question, please. [Edit] and remove the second question, the answer for which you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row. Also, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection probably not too important where you are now but concatenating user input into a query is very bad. If your record isn't inserted into the database, it'll throw an exception, not return 0. Do a try/catch and... hell, just show them the exception Message. Probably good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the Customer and identity column it will auto increment when the record inserts but you won't be able to know which one you just created if let's say 2 person add the data at the same time. There are alot of different ways to do it but looking at your code i assume you are pretty new to this so i'll give you a simple working solution.

You will need couple things:

1. You need a way to know the user using the software. Anything could be good as long as it's unique. If you don't have a user login you can use things like computer name (if on a domain), windows login name. etc
2. Add a new column to your table called `CreatedBy` or something like that.
3. Now when you insert the record add your unique user value you choose at step 1
4. After the `Insert` query do a `Select` query to get the highest `CustomerId` where the `CreatedBy` is the current user. This will give you all the data including the `CustomerId` you want.