# How to get the Inserted ID in Dotnet Core using Postgresql (Using RAW SQL)

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

**Issue**:  I can't get the new ID of the inserted entry into my POSTGRES Database on DotNet Core.  I am so depressed, i can't find this answer!

Here is the command that I am trying that DOES work when I use a postgres client. I am using RAW SQL commands to run the QUERY.

```
The SQL command that should work

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"INSERT INTO pulserelations (pulseid, create_time, modified_time) VALUES ({pulse_id}, now(),now()) RETURNING pulserelationid;");
```

I have verified the insert was successful.
The Return value of this function is always 1;

Additional Info

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=localdb;Username=yyyy;Password=xxxx");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

  public DbQuery<IDInsertQuery> get_id_of_insert_query {get;set;}
```

I have tried to even RE-QUERY the database after an insert using and that didn't work either

```
public class IDInsertQuery
{
public int currval;

}

    List<IDInsertQuery> list_id =  await _context.get_id_of_insert_query.FromSql($"select currval from currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('pulserelations', 'pulserelationid'));").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Maybe you want [`SqlQuery<TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_SqlQuery__1_System_String_System_Object___) ?

Comment: This does not seem available in Dotnet Core

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: I wish. Its not postgres nor dotnet core

Comment: What library and version are you using? EntityFramework v6.2 has `System.Data.Entity.Database` which has both `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync()` and `SqlQuery()` but EntityFrameworkCore's (v2.2.6) `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade` does not have either. Maybe I am just looking at the wrong library?

Comment: I am using EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4 and you are correct. DatabaseFascade does not have either.  (This is the problem)

Comment: Please Help! I can't code without solving this fairly simple problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL&DR:** Create an Output Variable to house the 'returning' ID query.

**Rationale**:  The INSERT statement returns an ID which can only be obtained using an OUTPUT paramater.  See Below.

The goal is to get an OUTPUT from a 'returning'

```
  NpgsqlParameter idOut = new NpgsqlParameter
        {
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        };
  await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"INSERT INTO pulserelations (pulseid, create_time, modified_time) VALUES ({pulse_id}, now(),now()) RETURNING pulserelationid;", idOut);
```