# How to get ID of an identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, many-to-many, identity

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables, `Users` and `Projects`.

The table that connects those two together is named `ProjectsUsers`.

Here is the description of the tables and their relationships:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Users"
(
    Email VARCHAR(320) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS PRIMARY KEY CHECK(LEN(Email) >= 3),
    --More....
);

CREATE TABLE "Projects"
(
    ProjectID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    --More....
);

CREATE TABLE "ProjectsUsers"
(
    UsersEmail VARCHAR(320) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS CHECK(LEN(UsersEmail) >= 3) NOT NULL,
    ProjectsID INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ProjectsUsers_PK PRIMARY KEY (UsersEmail, ProjectsID),
    CONSTRAINT ProjectsID_FK FOREIGN KEY (ProjectsID) REFERENCES Projects (ProjectID)  
               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    CONSTRAINT UsersEmail_FK FOREIGN KEY (UsersEmail) REFERENCES Users(Email) 
               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I am now trying to create a stored procedure that will insert a new project to the `Projects` table. After I add the project I want to create a reference to it in the `ProjectsUsers` table. The problem is, there is no possible way for me to know what the id of the project I just created - thus, I am unable to know what ID should I insert into the `ProjectsUsers`.

So if my stored procedure was something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Projects (Project, CreationDate, ProjectName) 
VALUES (@project,  GETDATE(), @email);

INSERT INTO ProjectsUsers VALUES (@email, ???)
```

How can I get the ID?

Comment: You need to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Projects (Project, CreationDate, ProjectName) 
VALUES (@project, SYSDATETIME(), @email);

DECLARE @ProjectID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO ProjectsUsers 
VALUES (@email, @ProjectID)
```

More [all the relevant details about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the official Microsoft Documentation site.

Comment: But if I work with multiple tables, how can the database "know" that I refer to the Identity of the table ```ProjectsUsers``` and not other's table identities?

Comment: @avivgood2: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` always refers to the **very last IDENTITY value** that was inserted - that's why you need to "grab it" right after the `INSERT` - you cannot wait for a few more statements before getting its value

Answer (score 0):

1. As Sean Lange mentions, you can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get last id inserted from within your proc
2. You can also use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause and get possibly many ids. You can output in the screen or in a table, but it wont work if you are selecting from a table that has triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OUTPUT` clause!  Do not use the various identity functions or variables.  This directly solves your problem:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (ProjectId int);
INSERT INTO Projects (Project, CreationDate, ProjectName) 
    OUTPUT inserted.ProjectId INTO @ids;
    VALUES (@project,  GETDATE(), @email);

INSERT INTO ProjectsUsers (UsersEmail, ProjectId)
    SELECT @email, ProjectId
    FROM @ids;
```

All the other methods of returning the identity have peculiarities:

- Perhaps they don't work when the `insert` has multiple statements.
- Perhaps concurrent inserts mess up the value.
- Perhaps they don't work well with triggers.