# doubled records with INSERT INTO sql statement inside VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to realise a simple sign up structure, and I am really new in `VBA` and `Access`. 
At the instruction `INSERT TO` it should add a record to the table USER. but it adds 2 identical records that have just a different userID, generated by the Automatic Numeration. Then I want to copy the last generated UserID in global variable valID, so that I can insert this UserID in a another table.
What am I doing wrong?

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO User ([Type], [FiscalCode], [Name], [Surname], [Birthdate], [Gender], [phoneNumber], [email], [country], [city], [postalCode], [street], [houseNumber])VALUES ('" & valtype & "', '" & valfis & "', '" & valname & "', '" & valsur & "', '" & valdata & "', '" & valgen & "', '" & valphone & "', '" & valemail & "','" & valcountry & "', '" & valcity & "', '" & valcode & "', '" & valstreet & "', " & valnum & ")")

valID = DLookup("[UserID]", "User", "[FiscalCode] = '" & valfis & "'")
```

after this code I want to do another instruction of the type insert to in a different table to insert in this new table as primary key the UserId I just obtained. this is the only other INSERT INTO inside the code.

Comment: Are you sure one of the records didnt already exist? There is nothing about that SQL that could create more than one record.

Comment: Also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: This statement adds only 1 row.If you see 2 new rows then either the one already existed or you executed the statement twice.

Comment: I'm doing this instruction on a void table, so no record already exists. I really can't understand what's the problem

Comment: How is this code being executed? You might literally be calling the `DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT...` statement twice somehow.

Comment: There's not enough detail included here to sort out the record duplication issue. As noted by others, that code won't insert multiple rows by itself.

Comment: In other words, please include the code around it in your question as well.

Comment: I added some more details, but the code is really simple and should be perform a simple task.

Comment: Why would UserID be a primary key in another table? This then is a one-to-one relationship. Why not just have one table?

Answer (score 1):

For this to happen, most likely form is bound to table and controls are bound to fields so user is inputting data into controls and then code runs INSERT as well thereby creating two records of same data.

A record is committed to table when one of the following happens:

1) table or query or bound form is closed

2) move to another record

3) run code to save

Remove the code.

Use form/subform arrangement for inputting parent record as well as dependent record in 'another' table.