# How can I reliably store an ID so that I can use it in another INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Python program that executes a series of SQL statements via a loop. It first inserts data in one table, then it inserts data in another table.

This table doesn't use an identity seed, but it does use a sequence value for the IDs so to get the next available number of the sequence, I do this `NEXT VALUE FOR transcript.nextid`

The second table needs the ID from the first table and get that by doing this `SELECT @ID = max(id) from transcript.transcript;`.

Here is one instance in that loop:

```
DECLARE @ID BigInt

--start loop 

INSERT INTO transcript.transcript (id, title, departmentId)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR transcript.nextid, 'binarySequence', 754)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

SELECT @ID = MAX(id) FROM transcript.transcript;

INSERT INTO transcript.externalSources (transcriptId, governanceId, hint)
VALUES (@ID, 00993846122, 'binarySequence');
```

The problem I am running into is that sometimes the value I get when doing this:

```
NEXT VALUE FOR transcript.nextid
```

does not always equal the value I get with this

```
SELECT @ID = MAX(id) from transcript.transcript;
```

Is there a way to reliably get the ID value?

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() should do the trick. I would suggest building a transaction and including this as the second statement so that they get execute at the same time to force it to get the correct value.

Comment: @easleyfixed SQL Server doesn't have `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. You can use the `OUTPUT` clause, though, to get certain values from `inserted`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand But the table doesn't use an  identity seed...just the next value in a sequence.  How would I output it so I could then use it in the next insert?

Comment: You can use `inserted.id` just like you would with an identity column. See my answer.

Comment: Wow, that is disturbing since in works in MYSQL, thanks for the info.

Comment: @easleyfixed Different products from different vendors so, yeah, there are more things different than the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the identity of an inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/how-to-get-the-identity-of-an-inserted-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause so that you can access the `inserted` values directly within the statement, and insert them directly into the other table. This prevents you from getting anyone else's `MAX()`, or using `serializable`, e.g.:

```
INSERT transcript.transcript(id, title, departmentId)
  OUTPUT inserted.id, 00993846122, inserted.title
  INTO transcript.externalSources(transcriptId, governanceId, hint)
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.nextid, 'binarySequence', 754;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/osNP6RPd) (but limited to `dbo` schema, sorry)

Comment: So I could replace my line above, `VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR transcript.nextid, 'binarySequence', 754)` with this?  Mine looks backwards compared to yours...is that wrong?

Comment: Also, would this only work if both tables have the same amount of columns to insert into?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You could even keep your `VALUES` it's just not the syntax I default to for one row (old habits). And no, the tables don't have to have the same number of columns. Notice the `OUTPUT` clause has a constant that doesn't come from either table. You can leave columns out (e.g. nullable or populated with default values). But `OUTPUT INTO` can't have _more_ columns than the target table. [Here's a slightly modified example](https://dbfiddle.uk/HLWZR27h).

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell and [a slightly different example](https://dbfiddle.uk/qVdQNs-8). The original only had the same number of columns because that's what your sample inserts have.

Answer (score 3):

When using an `identity` column, you can use `scope_identity()`.

But since you're using a `sequence`, one option is using `NEXT VALUE FOR` to set the variable **first**, then use this one variable for **both inserts**:

```
DECLARE @ID BigInt

--start loop 
SET @ID = NEXT VALUE FOR transcript.nextid;

INSERT INTO transcript.transcript (id, title, departmentId)
VALUES (@ID, 'binarySequence', 754)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

INSERT INTO transcript.externalSources (transcriptId, governanceId, hint)
VALUES (@ID, 00993846122, 'binarySequence');
```

This is especially useful if there are more than two tables (such that `OUTPUT`/`INTO` might not be adequate). The issue with this option is we're now crossing several statements that change different tables, so you should also think about using a transaction to ensure things can roll back cleanly in the event everything doesn't go as expected.

Comment: Also a good option, especially if the batch is more complex.