Oracle SQL - How insert the values from select statement and return the rows of values on the stored procedure
I've created a stored procedure, I know how to insert from the select statement to a table, my dilemma is how to return what's been inserted to the table on a stored procedure so it can be read on my vb.net solution.
Below is my script:
 PROCEDURE InsertEmailList(app_cd                    IN  VARCHAR2,
                           app_auth_key_value        IN  VARCHAR2,
                           refcsr                    OUT cursor_type)
 AS    
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO EmailListTable
    SELECT ID, emailAddress, name From BuyerList;

 END InsertEmailList;

How would the procedure return the whole table as output?
Thanks!

Can you clarify, you seem to be asking both to just return what was inserted, as well as the whole table.  Which is it?

It sounds like you want the results of the SELECT statement you already have to be both inserted into the other table and output by the sproc. That's not going to happen. You need another SELECT statement for the output.

@Dijkgraaf, As seen above, I've inserted some values to the table [EmailListTable], now I want what was inserted to the table [EmailListTable] to be the output of the procedure.

So are you suggesting to just select what's in the table, the table[EmailListTable] might have previous values, I just want the recent data that was inserted to the table.

Probably something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/how-to-get-the-identity-of-an-inserted-row but for Oracle.

Are any column values being auto-generated in the EmailListTable table? If not, you could simply repeat the same query as you are currently using, so get the data from BuyerList rather than EmailListTable. If there are additional, auto-generated columns then you can use a subquery that gets just the IDs from BuyerList and uses the result as a filter for data to retrieve from EmailListTable.

I've never tried to do this but, in SQL Server, you may be able to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to store the initial query results in something like a temp table but even more lightweight, then insert from there and query from there. Not sure whether Oracle has a similar feature. If it doesn't, you could use a temp table to achieve something similar but with worse performance.

How much data are you inserting at a time and in how many sessions?  You could run the query once, bulk collect the data into a local collection, and then insert the data from the collection into the destination table and return a cursor that selects from that local collection.  That works fine if you're inserting a couple thousand smallish rows in one or two sessions at a time but may put a serious dent in server memory if you're inserting millions of rows in hundreds of sessions at a time.

@jmcilhinney "...in SQL Server, you may be able to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to store the initial query results in something like a temp table but even more lightweight, then insert from there and query from there." The issue with this is, the CTE has a scope to only the next "normal" query. If you use the CTE in the SELECT... INTO, the CTE will no longer be in scope for a follow-up SELECT. So a temp table, or table variable, would be required. ;WITH Data AS (SELECT 1 AS One, 2 AS Two) SELECT * FROM Data SELECT One FROM Data will fail.
